# incompatibilities between LuaLaTeX and \typein ?

Tags: luatex, typein

The following ecm compiles fine with LaTeX and XeLaTeX, but doesn't work with LuaLaTeX :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\typein{test}
\end{document}
```

And here is the error :

```
Invalid \endlinechar.
<recently read> \@M 

l.4 \typein{test}

?
```

Comment: `\endlinechar` seems to get set to `\@M` which is 10000, a value normally used as maximum for penalties. The TeXBook states that for values <0 and >255 no endline character is appended to the line. Maybe in LuaTeX the value for `\endlinechar` is limited to some value below 10000 and therefore this causes an error?

Comment: The manual of luatex says in the section about modifications: "The upper limit to \endlinechar and \newlinechar is 127.". So it won't work.

Comment: `\endlinechar=-1` should work for the intended purpose. Note that even if luatex were to accept `\endlinechar=10000`, this would mean something completely different: in unicode, char 10000 is actually "UPPER RIGHT PENCIL"

Comment: @Taco, could you post an answer with the exact code (where should I write \endlinechar=-1 ?), please ?

Comment: I assume you will have to redefine `\typein`, but I assume this should be a job for the lualatex format itself. In any case, you will have to ask a latex expert, which I am definitely not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've submitted the bug to LaTeX bugs database and this is now fixed in TeXLive.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have to patch the kernel (untested):

```
\def\@xtypein[#1]#2{%
  \typeout{#2}%
  \@tempcnta\endlinechar
  \endlinechar\m@ne
  \read\@inputcheck to#1%
  \endlinechar\@tempcnta
  \@typein}
```

This should be done at format generation time; you might report it at the LaTeX mailing list (LATEX-L@LISTSERV.UNI-HEIDELBERG.DE).

Comment: this works. I also reported the bug.