# What is the difference between \ifx\somecommand\undefined and \ifdefined\somecommand\else?

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals

What is the difference between `\ifx\cyrdash\undefined` and `\ifdefined\cyrdash\else`? `\cyrdash`  is any macro.

Comment: Sorry for typos. Question should be: What is the difference between `\ifx\cyrdash\undefined` and `\ifdefined\else\cyrdash`?

Comment: I changed the question (and the title) to match the real problem.

Comment: Somewhat related, [macros - What does \begingroup\expandafter…\endgroup do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24393/what-does-begingroup-expandafter-endgroup-do)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Of course, they have different syntax.

1. `\ifx\cyrdash\undefined` is traditional way to test if a macro is undefined. Of course, `\undefined` sould *not* be defined.
2. There are `\ifdefined` and `\ifcsname` primitives in eTeX. They have no other side effects.
3. LaTeX's `\@ifundefined` test if a macro is defined or it has the same meaning of `\relax`. Furthermore, `\@ifundefined{undefinedfoo}{...}{...}` will makes `\undefinedfoo` to be `\relax`.

Normally, there is no difference between

```
\ifx\foo\undefined A \else B \fi
```

and

```
\ifdefined\foo B \else A \fi
```

eTeX primitives may be a little safer. Say, we don't need to worry about whether `\undefined` is really undefined.

However, these two usage are different:

```
% wrong
% \expandafter\ifx\csname foo\endcsname\undefined A \else B \fi % This is always false
\expandafter\ifx\csname foo\endcsname\relax A \else B \fi % This is \@ifundefined
```

and

```
\ifcsname foo\endcsname B \else A \fi
```

In fact, `\csname undefined\endcsname` makes `\undefined` to be `\relax`, while `\ifcsname undefined\endcsname` makes `\undefined` unchanged. That's why `\ifcsname` in eTeX is necessary.

---

Test code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\long\def\themeaning#1{\string#1: \meaning#1\par}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter\ttfamily

\def\known{abc}
\let\empty\relax

% initial
\themeaning\known
\themeaning\empty
\themeaning\unknown
\hrulefill

% useful eTeX extension
\ifdefined\known yes\else no\fi\par
\ifdefined\empty yes\else no\fi\par
\ifdefined\unknown yes\else no\fi\par
\hrulefill

% Or
\ifcsname known\endcsname yes\else no\fi\par
\ifcsname empty\endcsname yes\else no\fi\par
\ifcsname unknown\endcsname yes\else no\fi\par
\hrulefill

% the meanings are unchanged
\themeaning\known
\themeaning\empty
\themeaning\unknown
\hrulefill

% LaTeX2e kernel
\@ifundefined{known}{yes}{no}\par
\@ifundefined{empty}{yes}{no}\par
\@ifundefined{unknown}{yes}{no}\par
\hrulefill

% \unknown is changed
\themeaning\known
\themeaning\empty
\themeaning\unknown

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

According to [TeX by Topic](http://tex.loria.fr/general/texbytopic.pdf) `\ifx` tests macro equality in the following manner.

> Equality of tokens is tested in a stronger sense than the above by
>   `\ifx token1 token2`
>
> - Character tokens are equal for `\ifx` if they have the same character
>     code and category code.
> - Control sequence tokens are equal if they
>     represent the same TeX primitive, or have been similarly defined by
>     `\font`, `\countdef`, or some such. For example,
>
>   ```
>   \let\boxhor=\hbox  
>   \ifx\boxhor\hbox %is true  
>   \font\a=cmr10 \font\b=cmr10 \ifx\a\b %is true
>   ```
> - Control sequences are also equal if they are macros with the
>     same parameter text and replacement text, and the same status with
>     respect to `\outer` and `\long`. For example,
>
>   ```
>   \def\a{z} \def\b{z} \def\c1{z} \def\d{\a}  
>   \ifx\a\b %is true  
>   \ifx\a\c %is false  
>   \ifx\a\d %is false
>   ```
>
> Tokens following this test are not expanded.

The above refers to `ifcat` here, also found in TeX by Topic. I presume you mean `\@ifundefined` from the LaTeX kernel when you say `\ifundefined`. That is simply implemented in the following manner:

```
\expandafter \ifx \csname cmd name\endcsname \relax
```

It uses the fact that the `\csname` mechanism expands to `\relax` if the csname is not defined. So basically the biggest difference is that `\ifx` is more flexible, it allows you to check equality of tokens and not simply whether a csname is defined or not. Furthermore, `\ifx` takes a token, whereas `\@ifundefined` takes a csname.

Answer (score 5):

Both `\undefined` as well as `\ifundefined` are macros and there is no guarantee that they have not been redefined by a some package.

The roots of `ifundefined` can be found in Exercise 7.7 (p 40) in the TeXBook, where Knuth asked the reader to define such a macro.

> When `\csname` is used to define a control sequence for the first
>   time, that control sequence is made equivalent to `\relax` until it is
>   redefined. Use this fact to design a macro `\ifundefined#1` such that,
>   for example,
>
> ```
> \ifundefined{TeX} true text\else false text\fi
> ```
>
> expands to the true text if `\TeX` hasn't previously been defined, or if `\TeX` has
>   been `\let` equal to `\relax`; it should expand to the false text
>   otherwise.

You can examine their content using `meaning:`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
%\def\undefined{\relax}
\texttt{TeX: \meaning\TeX}\\
\texttt{ifundefined: \meaning\ifundefined}\\
\texttt{@ifundefined: \meaning\@ifundefined}\\
\texttt{undefined: \meaning\undefined}\\
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

As you can see in LaTeX, they are  equivalent. LaTeX also offers `@ifundefined`.