# Checking the mainmatter

Tags: conditionals, package-writing

I need to check where the text (from package .sty), if it is in the mainmatter section, then include some headers `\pagestyle{LL}`, if the other then `\pagestyle{plain}` or some other.
Construction `\ifx\@mainmattertrue\pagestyle{LL}\else\pagestyle{plain}\fi` in:

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{New}[2014/12/12]

\DeclareOption{LL}{\AtEndOfPackage{\llstyle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{textcase}


\def\ps@LL{

     %------------------Колонтитули---------------------
     %------------------Верхні--------------------------
     \renewcommand{\@evenhead}%
     {\raisebox{0pt}[\headheight][0pt]{% начало блока
            \vbox{\hbox to\textwidth{\strut
                    \small{\thepage\hfil\MakeUppercase{BlaBla}\hfil{GL}. \thechapter}}\hrule}}% конец блока
     }% конец макроопределения

     \renewcommand{\@oddhead}%
     {\raisebox{0pt}[\headheight][0pt]{% начало блока
            \vbox{\hbox to\textwidth{\strut
                    \small{{\S\hspace{1ex}}\thesection\hfil\MakeUppercase{Bla1}\hfil\thepage}}\hrule}}% конец блока
     }% конец макроопределения

    }



\def\@LLview{
    \ifx\@mainmattertrue\pagestyle{LL}\else\pagestyle{plain}\fi
    }


\def\llstyle
{
\@ifclassloaded{book}{\@LLview}{}
\@ifclassloaded{extbook}{\@LLview}{}
}

\endinput
```

does not work in

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[LL]{New}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[1-6]


\mainmatter
\chapter{One}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Why?

Comment: The standard `book` class makes that test for chapters, you can have a look at it.

Comment: Please add a [little detail](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) so we have something to test.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have done MWE in my post

Comment: If you want to activate the pagestyle with the start of `mainmatter`, redefine or patch `mainmatter`. When the package is executed, you cannot be in mainmatter. Next topic: [Difference between \if and \ifx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127502)

Answer (score 4):

The `book` class defines the `\if@mainmatter` conditional. So

```
\if@mainmatter
   <we are in the main matter>
\else
   <we aren't in the main matter>
\fi
```

is the scheme for the code you need. For instance

```
\def\@LLview{%
  \if@mainmatter
    \pagestyle{LL}%
  \else
    \pagestyle{plain}%
 \fi
}
```

This indentation style is not mandatory, but I find it convenient. With your style it could be

```
\def\@LLview{%
    \if@mainmatter\pagestyle{LL}\else\pagestyle{plain}\fi
    }
```

(the `%` at the end of the first line *is* needed).

Note that `\if@mainmatter` is initially set to true. The commands `\frontmatter` and `\backmatter` set it to false, while `\mainmatter` resets it to true.

The `\@mainmattertrue` command is used for setting the conditional to return true, and there's the similar `\@mainmatterfalse`.

Comment: I try for code pointed in topic above. But again it does not work. \pagestyle{LL} is applied for \chapter{Intro} which is in frontmatter too.

Comment: @sergiokapone Of course: you just execute the command `\@LLview` once. It's probably better adding the page style declaration directly to the code for `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`.

Comment: @egref Yes, you right. It is bertter to redefine \mainmatter