# if statement problem

Tags: conditionals, rules

I am having a problem with some code and I could use some help. I have been using this implementation for a long time now and no problems before.

Here is how I store all my variables

```
\newcommand{\@srulesI}{}
\newcommand{\@srulesII}{}
\newcommand{\srules}[2]{
    \renewcommand\@srulesI{#1}
    \renewcommand\@srulesII{#2}}%%%%%
```

Here is the logic for it.

```
\if\@srulesII\@emptymacro
\else
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \raggedright
        {\bfseries \rule{0em}{1.5em}\@srulesI}

        \@srulesII
    \end{minipage}
\fi
```

These pieces of code work

```
\srules{}{}%%%%%
\srules{}{asdf}%%%%%
\srules{asdf}{}%%%%%
\srules{asdf}{asdf}%%%%%
\srules{asdf}{asdf\rule{0.5in}{0.5in}}%%%%%
```

This piece of code doesnt work, which is coincidentally the one I need.

```
\srules{asdf}{\rule{0.5in}{0.5in}}%%%%%
```

It gives an error of "Incomplete \if; all text was ignored after line 40. "

Does anyone know why? I dont know why the `\rule` makes the compiler have a fit.

Second question. Is what I am doing really the best way to declare and store variables? Cause I have like 50 variables and my `.cls` file is getting huge.

Comment: See [Difference between `\if` and `\ifx`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127502/) for understanding why `\ifx` should be used instead of `\if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For macro-comparison, use `\ifx`, not `\if`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@srulesI}{}
\newcommand{\@srulesII}{}
\newcommand{\srules}[2]{
  \renewcommand\@srulesI{#1}
  \renewcommand\@srulesII{#2}}%%%%%
\newcommand{\@emptymacro}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\srules{asdf}{\rule{0.5in}{0.5in}}%%%%%
\makeatletter
\ifx\@srulesII\@emptymacro
\else
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \raggedright
    {\bfseries \rule{0em}{1.5em}\@srulesI}

    \@srulesII
  \end{minipage}
\fi
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

---

In answer to your second question, it really depends on your user interface. Note that arguments to macros are limited to 9, although [that can be increased](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2132/5764). A key-value interface in such instances are typically preferred.