# Problem with iffalse in newcommand

Tags: macros, errors, ifthenelse

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcounter{example}[subsection]

\newcommand{\challenge}[3]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip\noindent \textbf{Challenge~\theexample.}
    #1
    \vskip0.2cm
    \noindent\textbf{Solution}: #2
    \vskip0.2cm
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\noindent\textbf{Notes}: #3}}


\begin{document}
\challenge{
    Write a note.
}{
    We simply write a note.
}{
    A note.
}

\challenge{
    Do not write any notes.
}{
    We simply leave the last argument empty.
}{}

\challenge{
    Demonstrate that notes can cause problems
}{
    We simply put a matrix to the notes.
}{
    Let $\varepsilon > 0$
%       and 
%       $$
%       A = \begin{matrix}
%       1
%       \end{matrix}
%       $$
%       be a matrix
        .
}
\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image: output]

When I uncomment the matrix part, I get the error:

> line 46: Undefined control sequence. }
>    : Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 46.

The line 46 is where the closing } for the third argument of the third challenge is.

I haven't faced any problems when I put the matrices etc. in any or both of the first two arguments.

Comment: I think this is a problem with the nested `\if` from `\ifthenelse` and the `math mode` introduced with `\[...\]`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not sure that this is completely true: If I replace the matrix part with `$$A = 2$$`, it compiles as expected.

Comment: I actually meant the `\if` command internally used in `matrix`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it's more just that ifthenelse is a protected edef, so environments don't work unless you sprinkle with \protect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: What should be be protected then? `\protect\begin{matrix}`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\protect\begin` and `\protect\end` would work but really the answer is not to do that but to use a better test for empty, either xparse or simply `\if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else\noindent\textbf{Notes}: #3\fi}` Or if using `ifthenelse` just to protect the whole thing eg via a toks register as you did below

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well, please add your answer with `\if\relax\detokenize` then. The token register was my first idea. I am not really much into `\ifthenelse`, yet, so don't really know how it is defined

Comment: See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) for reasons why avoiding `$$` in LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

Ifthenelse fully expands its first argument, so fragile commands have to be `\protected`

```
You could use

{
    Let $\varepsilon > 0$
       and 
       $$
       A = \protect\begin{matrix}
       1
       \protect\end{matrix}
       $$
       be a matrix
        .
}
```

But better really would be to use a better test for empty argument

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcounter{example}[subsection]

\newcommand{\challenge}[3]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip\noindent \textbf{Challenge~\theexample.}
    #1
    \vskip0.2cm
    \noindent\textbf{Solution}: #2
    \vskip0.2cm
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else\noindent\textbf{Notes}: #3\fi}


\begin{document}
\challenge{
    Write a note.
}{
    We simply write a note.
}{
    A note.
}

\challenge{
    Do not write any notes.
}{
    We simply leave the last argument empty.
}{}

\challenge{
    Demonstrate that notes can cause problems
}{
    We simply put a matrix to the notes.
}{
    Let $\varepsilon > 0$
       and 
       $$
       A = \begin{matrix}
       1
       \end{matrix}
       $$
       be a matrix
        .
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, now the third argument can be also `{  }`.

Comment: @Antoine no, as written a space will count as non-empty but there are tests that ignore white space, I'll find a link...

Comment: see eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263733/whats-the-best-practice-way-to-test-whether-parameter-is-empty

Comment: I am so sorry, the line in the real text I am writing, went to the next page. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

I used a `token` register to preexpand the content of `#3` in order to silence the nested `\if...` there.

However, I suggest to use something like `xparse` rather with optional arguments (see the other answer at the end of this post)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcounter{example}[subsection]
\newtoks\daviddoesnotliketoksasname
\newcommand{\challenge}[3]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip% \par?
  \noindent%
  \textbf{Challenge~\theexample.}
  #1%
  \vskip0.2cm
  \noindent\textbf{Solution}: #2%
  \vskip0.2cm
  \daviddoesnotliketoksasname={#3}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\the\daviddoesnotliketoksasname}{}}{}{\noindent\textbf{Notes}: \the\toks}%
}


\begin{document}
\challenge{
    Write a note.
}{
    We simply write a note.
}{
    A note.
}

\challenge{
    Do not write any notes.
}{
    We simply leave the last argument empty.
}{}

\challenge{
    Demonstrate that notes can cause problems
}{
    We simply put a matrix to the notes.
}{%
  Let $\varepsilon > 0$
  and 
  \[
  A = \begin{matrix}
    1
  \end{matrix}
  \]
  be a matrix.
}
\end{document}
```

**Update with a `xparse` version**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcounter{example}[subsection]

\NewDocumentCommand{\challenge}{+m+m+o}{%
  \refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip% \par?
  \noindent%
  \textbf{Challenge~\theexample.}
  #1%
  \vskip0.2cm
  \noindent\textbf{Solution}: #2%
  \vskip0.2cm
  \IfValueT{#3}{%
    \noindent\textbf{Notes}: #3%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\challenge{%
    Write a note.
}{%
    We simply write a note.
}[
    A note.
]

\challenge{%
    Do not write any notes.
}{%
    We simply leave the last argument empty.
}

\challenge{%
    Demonstrate that notes can cause problems
}{
    We simply put a matrix to the notes.
}[%
  Let $\varepsilon > 0$
  and 
  \[
  A = \begin{matrix}
    1 & 5  \\
    3 & 4 
  \end{matrix}
  \]
  be a matrix.
]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\toks` is _not_ a good name for a scratch token register:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I have chosen a better name now -- you will like it ;-)

Comment: Thank you, that works. I have noticed `\par?` "question" ... I simply copied this if-else solution from somewhere else and I didn't really pay attention to it. I do not know what does par do, so I removed it now and everything is still OK.

Comment: hmph you still have same in the xparse one:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Not any longer, that's a copy-over-error ;-)

Comment: OK +1 now it doesn't completely break latex by redefining primitives:-)

Comment: @Antoine: Yes, but glueing fragments together is not the best way to achieve things

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well, that was actually my plan -- breaking LaTeX ;-)