# cls Variable Fallback

Tags: document-classes, variable

> Since I am not experienced with writing `cls` so it may be a very simple question and is a duplicate but I cannot use the exact word to express it.

Here is what I want to achieve in this cls:

- There are two commands, `\author` and `instructor` (this is defined in cls), each taking an argument.
- Normally, they can be set separately.
- However, if `\author` or `\instructor` is empty (i.e. `\author{}`, `\instructor{}`) or `\author` or `\instructor` is not defined by the user, they should use a **fallback**, `\@author` will be `\@instructor` or `\@instructor` be assigned `\@author` according to which one is missing.
- If both are missed, maybe just do nothing.

This is a **MnWE**. It compiles with error. (Strangely, with my full cls, it compiles fine but the `\if` statement does not seem right and the result is wrong.)

```tex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{myclass}
    \LoadClass{article}
    
    \let\@instructor\@empty
    \newcommand{\instructor}[1]{\gdef\@instructor{#1}}
    
    \newcommand{\test}{\@instructor}
    
    \makeatletter
    \if\@instructor\@empty
        \def\@instructor\@author % author is the instructor (if not specified)
    \else
        \if\@author\@empty
            \def\@author\@instructor % instructor is the author (if not specified)
        \fi
    \fi
    \makeatother
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\author{Author Name}
% \instructor{Instructor Name}
\instructor{}

\begin{document}
    \test{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifx` not `\if` (in both cases) and `\let` not `\def` you can not do `\def\something\somethingelse`   t needs braces

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a million for pointing out the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle), I finally solved the problem.
The difference between `\ifx` and `\if` is pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127502/234654).

The test file needs some changes so as to demonstrate the function (here I use the `\maketitle` command as an example):

```tex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClass{article}

\let\@instructor\@empty
\newcommand{\instructor}[1]{\gdef\@instructor{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{
    \ifx\@instructor\@empty
        \let\@instructor\@author % author is the instructor (if not specified)
    \else
        \ifx\@author\@empty
            \let\@author\@instructor % instructor is the author (if not specified)
        \fi
    \fi
    \@instructor
}
\makeatother
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\author{Author Name}
% \instructor{Instructor Name}
\instructor{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

which now works out fine.

Comment: For the whole `cls` file, this class has been uploaded to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/seu-ml-assign).