# How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro?

Tags: macros, expansion

I am looking for an informative answer here. If I want to append to a macro, I have a couple of options, each depending on whether I want the items fully expanded, partially expanded (a certain number of times), or not expanded, right?

Today I am choosing to use the **boatload of `\expandafter`s** approach.

## Storing/Collecting Items in a Macro Conforming to "Userspace" Macro Naming Scheme

*no numerals, no symbols, no spaces*

```
\def\appendtolist#1#2{% #1 = Macro Name (list) #2=New Item to Append
  \ifx#1\undefined \def#1{#2}\else% Macro Existence Check  
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1,#2}\fi% #1=Expand Macro List,  #2=New Item
}%
```

## Storing/Collecting Items in a Macro Defined with `\csname`

*contains anything with tradeoff that you have to use a boatload of `\expandafter`s*

```
\def\appendtolist#1#2{% #1 = Macro Name (list) #2=New Item to Append
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}\else% Macro Existence Check  
  %\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1,#2}\fi% Headache-causing line when trying to surround #1 with \csname
  %\expandafter\def\expandafter\csname #1-names\endcsname% I became lost at this point
}%
```

## Problem / Question Redefined

See headache-causing line above. How can I **know** the right number of `\expandafter`s beyond the shadow of a doubt without using a trial-and-error approach?

My thoughts up until the stopping point were:

- Ok, I need `\expandafter` to expand `\csname` into a macro
- Then I `\expandafter` to expand the new definition of that macro before I TeX defines it.

---

**Notes**

- Why I have `\relax` in place of `\undefined` when using `csname` is nicely described here:  [What is the difference between \ifx\somecommand\undefined and \ifdefined\somecommand\else?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31652/what-is-the-difference-between-ifx-somecommand-undefined-and-ifdefined-somecom/31658#31658)
- I saw a formula somewhere like `2^n-1` (`n` being number of expansions needed) from egreg. I hope to find that link and put it here.

Comment: It's `2^n-1`, not `2(n-1)`

Comment: @egreg Fixed! So 4 expansions=`(2^4)-1`=`(16)-1`=`15`. That is so many `\expandafter`s and therefore not elegant. The output of TeX is quite elegant, however.

Comment: @macmadness86 Use `etoolbox`, it's super useful.

Comment: @Manuel "Today I am choosing to use the boatload of \expandafters approach." ;) Also, egreg already demonstrated the simplified etoolbox version in his answer. But thanks for putting your two cents in anyway.

Comment: @macmadness86 Didn't see that.

Comment: See also [tex core - How does your mind bend \expandafter to its will? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161064/how-does-your-mind-bend-expandafter-to-its-will)..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The primitive `\expandafter` carries out exactly one expansion and leaves the result of this in the input stream. Thus

```
\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname
```

with `#1` as `foo` is equivalent after one expansion to

```
\def\foo
```

To get things correct, you have to track how many expansions are required and to know the number of `\expandafter` commands you need (1, 3, 7, ..., for 1, 2, 3, ... expansions, respectively). We also have some 'tricks' available.

In

```
\def\appendtolist#1#2{% #1 = Macro Name (list) #2=New Item to Append
....
```

need to first do a test for existence (which you already have) then to expand `\csname #1\endcsname` to the command name in two places. This is best done as

```
\expandafter\def\csname#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   {\csname #1\endcsname,#2}%
```

There is a 'trick' here. We first expand past the `\def` to start constructing the name of the macro we want for storage. At the end of the `\csname ...` construct, we need three `\expandafter`s (and two sets as there is a brace to skip over). That's the case as we need to do two expansions: the first to turn `\csname #1\endcsname` into the macro name (say `\foo`), and the second to expand `\foo` into the content of `\foo`.

Expansion is all about tracking exactly what is in the input stream, and being aware of how many steps you require.

Comment: Great answer! You forgot to add a disclaimer: *Learning expansion could lead to headaches, unusual outbreaks of aggression including, but not limited to, foul language*.

Comment: "two sets as there is a brace to skip over" implies a change to our formula `2^n-1`. I am certainly no math expert but it would seem to calculate `\expandafter`s with braces: 1 brace=b=1, so`b(2(2^n-1))`. If there were two braces, I would need 12 `\expandafter`s. In other words, a boatload of them ;)

Comment: @macmadness86 I don't mean the number of `\expandafter`s required in each place, I mean that to skip over the brace we need them in two places: `\expandafter\foo\expandafter\bar\expandafter\baz\target` expands the target only once but has to skip over three things, for example.

Comment: Yep, we're on the same wavelength (I understood "sets"). Thanks. I just want to be able to predict *when* I need sets. I would not have guessed to put the first set *before* the `\endcsname`, for example. But I guess that is because `\endcsname` is in itself a second control sequence whereas`\def` is only one. I found a similar explanation of `\csname name\expandafter\endcsname\token
` here for future reference:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519/13552

Comment: @macmadness86 You need to `\expandafter` each token you want to skip. In the case of `\csname ...\endcsname` the trick is that as this also does expansion we _don't_ have to skip each token in the name, but can just do the `\expandafter` at the end of the name, immediately before `\endcsname`.

Answer (score 16):

## Formula for the amount of `\expandafter` that need to be inserted.

**If you wish to have TeX "jump" over L tokens in order to have TeX beforehand produce the K-level-expansion outgoing from the (L+1)<sup>th</sup> token, this requires to have inserted (2<sup>K</sup>-1) `\expandafter`-tokens in front of each of these L tokens that are to be "juped" over.**

**Thus:**
**If you wish to have TeX "jump" over L tokens in order to have TeX beforehand produce the K-level-expansion outgoing from the (L+1)<sup>th</sup> token, this requires the insertion of L·(2<sup>K</sup>-1) `\expandafter` into the .tex-input.**

The basic procedure is successively inserting `\expandafter`-chains.
Each `\expandafter`-chain yields another level of expansion.
The `\expandafter`-chain inserted the last but zero will deliver the first-level-expansion.
The `\expandafter`-chain inserted the last but one will deliver the second-level-expansion.
...
The `\expandafter`-chain inserted the last but (K-1) will deliver the K-level-expansion.

The point hereby is:

Having added another `\expandafter`-chain means having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over by the `\expandafter`-chain that is to be added.
Therefore you need to trace the number of tokens that should be "jumped" over by adding the new `\expandafter`-chain.

Example:

Having TeX "jump" over four tokens in order to have TeX beforehand produce the 2-level-expansion outgoing from the 5<sup>th</sup> token requires the insertion of L·(2<sup>K</sup>-1)  `\expandafter` while L=4 and K=2, thus requires the insertion of 4·(2<sup>2</sup>-1) `\expandafter`= 12 `\expandafter` into the .tex-input:

```tex
%|the \expand|the \expand|
%|after-chain|after-chain|
%|in this co-|in this co-|
%|lumn deli- |lumn deli- |
%|vers       |vers       |
%|1-level-ex-|2-level-ex-|
%|pansion out|pansion out|
%|-going from|-going from|
%|\Fifth     |\Fifth     |
%|     |     |     |     |
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter            \First  % _________ 1x(2^K-1)=1x(2^2-1) \expandafter inserted in front of \First
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter            \Second % _________ 1x(2^K-1)=1x(2^2-1) \expandafter inserted in front of \Second
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter            \third  % _________ 1x(2^K-1)=1x(2^2-1) \expandafter inserted in front of \Third
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter            \Fourth % _________ 1x(2^K-1)=1x(2^2-1) \expandafter inserted in front of \Fourth
 \Fifth                          %A total of Lx(2^K-1)=4x(2^2-1) \expandafter inserted into the .tex-input
```

## Let's look at the scenario of successively adding `\expandafter`-chains in order to have TeX beforehand produce the K-level-expansion outgoing from the (1+1)<sup>th</sup> token (= the 2<sup>nd</sup> token).

**It is required to insert 1·(2<sup>K</sup>-1) `\expandafter`=2<sup>K</sup>-1 `\expandafter` into the .tex-input.**

*(Assume `\First` is the 1<sup>st</sup> token before insertion of `\expandafter` and `\Second`is the 2<sup>nd</sup> token before insertion of `\expandafter`.)*

---

**Case K=0** — Have TeX produce 0-level-expansion outgoing from `\Second`:
*(0-level-expansion outgoing from an expandable token = expansion outgoing from that token does not get triggered.)*
0 tokens in front of `\Second` should be "jumped" over.
There are/is 2<sup>0</sup> tokens = 1 token in front of `\Second`. 1 of them is not an `\expandafter`-token.
You need to insert 2<sup>0</sup>-1 `\expandafter` = 0 `\expandafter`:

```tex
\First\Second
```

---

**Case K=1** — Have TeX produce 1-level-expansion outgoing from `\Second`:
In order to obtain one more level of expansion, another `\expandafter`-chain needs to be added to the code that was produced for achieving case K=0.   This implies the insertion of an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over.
From case K=0 we know that there are  2<sup>0</sup> tokens in front of `\Second`  that should be "jumped" over.
Having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each of these tokens yields 2·(2<sup>0</sup>) tokens=2<sup>1</sup> tokens in front of `\Second`.  1 of them is not an `\expandafter`-token.
You need to insert 2<sup>1</sup>-1 `\expandafter`:

```tex
%|the \expand|
%|after-chain|
%|in this co-|
%|lumn deli- |
%|vers       |
%|1-level-ex-|
%|pansion out|
%|-going from|
%|\Second    |
%|     |     |
 \expandafter\First
 \Second
```

---

**Case K=2** — Have TeX produce 2-level-expansion outgoing from `\Second`:
In order to obtain one more level of expansion, another `\expandafter`-chain needs to be added to the code that was produced for achieving case K=1.   This implies the insertion of an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over.
From case K=1 we know that there are  2<sup>1</sup> tokens in front of `\Second`  that should be "jumped" over.
Having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each of these tokens yields 2·(2<sup>1</sup>) tokens=2<sup>2</sup> tokens in front of `\Second`.  1 of them is not an `\expandafter`-token.
You need to insert 2<sup>2</sup>-1 `\expandafter`:

```tex
%|the \expand|the \expand|
%|after-chain|after-chain|
%|in this co-|in this co-|
%|lumn deli- |lumn deli- |
%|vers       |vers       |
%|1-level-ex-|2-level-ex-|
%|pansion out|pansion out|
%|-going from|-going from|
%|\Second    |\Second    |
%|     |     |     |     |
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter            \First
 \Second
```

---

**Case K=3** — Have TeX produce 3-level-expansion outgoing from `\Second`:
In order to obtain one more level of expansion, another `\expandafter`-chain needs to be added to the code that was produced for achieving case K=2.   This implies the insertion of an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over.
From case K=2 we know that there are  2<sup>2</sup> tokens in front of `\Second`  that should be "jumped" over.
Having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each of these tokens yields 2·(2<sup>2</sup>) tokens=2<sup>3</sup> tokens in front of `\Second`.  1 of them is not an `\expandafter`-token.
You need to insert 2<sup>3</sup>-1 `\expandafter`:

```tex
%|the \expand|the \expand|the \expand|
%|after-chain|after-chain|after-chain|
%|in this co-|in this co-|in this co-|
%|lumn deli- |lumn deli- |lumn deli- |
%|vers       |vers       |vers       |
%|1-level-ex-|2-level-ex-|3-level-ex-|
%|pansion out|pansion out|pansion out|
%|-going from|-going from|-going from|
%|\Second    |\Second    |\Second    |
%|     |     |     |     |     |     |
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter            \expandafter
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter                        \First
 \Second
```

---

**Case K=4** — Have TeX produce 4-level-expansion outgoing from `\Second`:
In order to obtain one more level of expansion, another `\expandafter`-chain needs to be added to the code that was produced for achieving case K=3.   This implies the insertion of an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over.
From case K=3 we know that there are  2<sup>3</sup> tokens in front of `\Second`  that should be "jumped" over.
Having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each of these tokens yields 2·(2<sup>3</sup>) tokens=2<sup>4</sup> tokens in front of `\Second`.  1 of them is not an `\expandafter`-token.
You need to insert 2<sup>4</sup>-1 `\expandafter`:

```tex
%|the \expand|the \expand|the \expand|the \expand|
%|after-chain|after-chain|after-chain|after-chain|
%|in this co-|in this co-|in this co-|in this co-|
%|lumn deli- |lumn deli- |lumn deli- |lumn deli- |
%|vers       |vers       |vers       |vers       |
%|1-level-ex-|2-level-ex-|3-level-ex-|4-level-ex-|
%|pansion out|pansion out|pansion out|pansion out|
%|-going from|-going from|-going from|-going from|
%|\Second    |\Second    |\Second    |\Second    |
%|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter            \expandafter
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter                        \expandafter
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter            \expandafter
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter                                     \First
 \Second
```

---

**Case ...**

---

Get the picture?

By the way:

There was introduced some indentation providing a visible impression where things are split up in columns.
One column is one `\expandafter`-chain delivering one level of expansion.
If you count the amount of `\expandafter` per column/per `\expandafter`-chain from the rightmost column to the leftmost column, this yields:
1+2+4+8+... = ∑<sub>i=1..K</sub>{2<sup>(i-1)</sup>}=2<sup>K</sup>-1.

In case of obtaining 4-level-expansion outgoing from `\Second` you have 4 columns of `\expandafter` holding  1+2+4+8 `\expandafter`= ∑<sub>i=1..4</sub>{2<sup>(i-1)</sup>} `\expandafter`= 2<sup>4</sup>-1 `\expandafter`.

Adding another `\expandafter`-chain for obtaining 5-level-expansion outgoing from `\Second` means adding an `\expandafter` in front of the token `\First` and adding an `\expandafter` in front of each of the 1+2+4+8 `\expandafter` that are already there.
This yields 1+2·(1+2+4+8) `\expandafter`=1+2+4+8+16 `\expandafter` = ∑<sub>i=1..5</sub>{2<sup>(i-1)</sup>} `\expandafter` = 2<sup>5</sup>-1 `\expandafter`.

Adding another `\expandafter`-chain for obtaining 6-level-expansion outgoing from `\Second` means adding an `\expandafter` in front of the token `\First` and adding an `\expandafter` in front of each of the 1+2+4+8+16 `\expandafter` that are already there.
This yields 1+2·(1+2+4+8+16) `\expandafter`=1+2+4+8+16+32 `\expandafter` = ∑<sub>i=1..6</sub>{2<sup>(i-1)</sup>} `\expandafter` = 2<sup>6</sup>-1 `\expandafter`.

## Now let's think about the scenario of successively adding `\expandafter`-chains in order to have TeX beforehand produce the K-level-expansion outgoing from the (L+1)<sup>th</sup> token.

*(After inserting `\expandafter`, the (L+1)<sup>th</sup> token won't be the (L+1)<sup>th</sup> token any more. Therefore the token which is the (L+1)<sup>th</sup> token before insertion of `\expandafter` will be referred to as "(L+1)-token"—in some places "(L+1)" is an ordinal number, in other places it is a nominal number.)*

---

**Case K=0** — Have TeX produce 0-level-expansion outgoing from the (L+1)-token before processing L tokens in front of the expansion-result:
*(0-level-expansion outgoing from an expandable token = expansion outgoing from that token does not get triggered.)*
The (L+1)-token is the (L+1)<sup>th</sup>-token in the token-stream.
There are 0 tokens in front of the (L+1)-token that should be "jumped" over.
There are L tokens = L·(2<sup>0</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token. L of them are not `\expandafter`-tokens.
You need to insert L·(2<sup>0</sup>)-L `\expandafter`=L·(2<sup>0</sup>-1) `\expandafter`=0 `\expandafter`.

---

**Case K=1** — Have TeX produce 1-level-expansion outgoing from the (L+1)-token before processing L tokens in front of the expansion-result:
In order to obtain one more level of expansion, another `\expandafter`-chain needs to be added to the code that was produced for achieving case K=0.   This implies the insertion of an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over.
From case K=0 we know that there are  L·(2<sup>0</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token that should be "jumped" over.
Having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each of these tokens yields 2·(L·(2<sup>0</sup>)) tokens = L·(2<sup>1</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token. L of them are not `\expandafter`-tokens.
You need to insert L·(2<sup>1</sup>)-L `\expandafter`=L·(2<sup>1</sup>-1) `\expandafter`.

---

**Case K=2** — Have TeX produce 2-level-expansion outgoing from the (L+1)-token before processing L tokens in front of the expansion-result:
In order to obtain one more level of expansion, another `\expandafter`-chain needs to be added to the code that was produced for achieving case K=1.   This implies the insertion of an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over.
From case K=1 we know that there are  L·(2<sup>1</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token that should be "jumped" over.
Having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each of these tokens yields 2·(L·(2<sup>1</sup>)) tokens = L·(2<sup>2</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token. L of them are not `\expandafter`-tokens.
You need to insert L·(2<sup>2</sup>)-L `\expandafter`=L·(2<sup>2</sup>-1) `\expandafter`.

---

**Case K=3** — Have TeX produce 3-level-expansion outgoing from the (L+1)-token before processing L tokens in front of the expansion-result:
In order to obtain one more level of expansion, another `\expandafter`-chain needs to be added to the code that was produced for achieving case K=2.   This implies the insertion of an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over.
From case K=2 we know that there are  L·(2<sup>2</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token that should be "jumped" over.
Having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each of these tokens yields 2·(L·(2<sup>2</sup>)) tokens = L·(2<sup>3</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token. L of them are not `\expandafter`-tokens.
You need to insert L·(2<sup>3</sup>)-L `\expandafter`=L·(2<sup>3</sup>-1) `\expandafter`.

---

**Case K=4** — Have TeX produce 4-level-expansion outgoing from the (L+1)-token before processing L tokens in front of the expansion-result:
In order to obtain one more level of expansion, another `\expandafter`-chain needs to be added to the code that was produced for achieving case K=3.   This implies the insertion of an `\expandafter`-token in front of each token that should be "jumped" over.
From case K=3 we know that there are  L·(2<sup>3</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token that should be "jumped" over.
Having inserted an `\expandafter`-token in front of each of these tokens yields 2·(L·(2<sup>3</sup>)) tokens = L·(2<sup>4</sup>) tokens in front of the (L+1)-token. L of them are not `\expandafter`-tokens.
You need to insert L·(2<sup>4</sup>)-L `\expandafter`=L·(2<sup>4</sup>-1) `\expandafter`.

---

**Case ...**

---

## There are tricks for reducing the amount of `\expandafter`.

Some tricks have to do with the fact that expansion is triggered by tokens like `\if` and `\ifcat` and `\romannumeral` and `\csname`.

Other tricks have to do with having TeX flip macro arguments around.

**E.g., using TeX's `#{`-notation, you can define a macro `\name`** which does take tokens before the first opening brace for an argument and causes another (internal) macro to take tokens nested into the first opening brace and the corresponding closing brace for another/a second argument.

This way you don't need to write `\expandafter`-chains for starting `\csname`-expansion.

I elaborated on the `\name`-macro in [the thread "Define a control sequence after that a space matters" which was started at TeX - LaTeX StackExchange in November 10, 2016](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338784/118714).

Basically the macro `\name` is one of those things that are about having TeX flip macro arguments around.

### Let's have a look at taking advantage of `\romannumeral`-expansion.

`\romannumeral` triggers expansion until either it is clear that an error-message needs to be triggered or TeX found a set of tokens that forms a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.
In the not so interesting case of the number denoted by the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity found being positive, TeX delivers a set of explicit character-tokens of category 12(other) which forms the representation of that number in lowercase roman numerals.
In the more interesting case of the number denoted by the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity found being not positive, TeX  silently not delivers any token at all but swallows/removes/discards the tokens that form the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.

Therefore `\romannumeral` can be (ab?)used for triggering a lot of expansion-work as long as in the end the leading tokens from the result of the expansion-cascade form a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity which denotes a non-positive number.

You can create a macro `\Expandtimes{<number K>}` which takes advantage of `\romannumeral`-expansion in the way that the sequence
`\romannumeral\Expandtimes{<number K>}`
needs only one "hit" by `\expandafter` for producing K "hits" by `\expandafter`.

`\romannumeral\Expandtimes{<number K>}` reduces the amount of `\expandafter`-chains that is needed to only one `\expandafter`-chain.

Syntax:

`\romannumeral\Expandtimes{<number K>}<token sequence>` → `K` times the leading token of `<token sequence>` will be "hit" by `\expandafter` .
In expansion contexts the leading `\romannumeral` being "hit" by one `\expandafter` is sufficient for obtaining these `K` "hits" by `\expandafter` on the leading token of `<token sequence>`.

E.g., with

```tex
\def\top{\first 0 }
\def\first{\second1 }
\def\second{\third2 }
\def\third{\fourth3 }
\def\fourth{\fifth4 }
\def\fifth{\sixth5 }
\def\sixth{6 }
```

`\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{0}\top` → `\string\top`

`\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{1}\top` → `\string\first0`

`\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{2}\top` → `\string\second1 0`

`\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{3}\top` → `\string\third2 1 0`

`\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{4}\top` → `\string\fourth3 2 1 0`

`\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{5}\top` → `\string\fifth4 3 2 1 0`

`\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{6}\top` → `\string\sixth5 4 3 2 1 0`

`\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{7}\top` → `\string6 5 4 3 2 1 0`

There are several ways of implementing `\Expandtimes`.
(A boring way is:

```tex
\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00

% A check is needed for finding out if an argument is catcode-11-"d" while there are only 
% the possibilities that the argument is either a single catcode-11-"d"
% or a single catcode-12-"m":
\def\innerdfork#1d#2#3dd{#2}%
\def\dfork#1{\innerdfork#1{\firstoftwo}d{\secondoftwo}dd}%

% By means of \romannumeral create as many catcode-12-characters m as expansion-steps are to take place.
% Then by means of recursion for each of these m double the amount of `\expandafter`-tokens and
% add one `\expandafter`-token within \innerExp's first argument.

\def\Expandtimes#1{\expandafter\innerExp\expandafter{\expandafter}\romannumeral\number\number#1 000d}
\def\innerExp#1#2{\dfork{#2}{#1\stopromannumeral}{\innerExp{#1#1\expandafter}}}

Now testing \tt\string\Expandtimes:

\def\top{\first 0 }
\def\first{\second1 }
\def\second{\third2 }
\def\third{\fourth3 }
\def\fourth{\fifth4 }
\def\fifth{\sixth5 }
\def\sixth{6 }

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{0}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{1}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{2}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{3}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{4}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{5}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{6}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{7}\top

\bye
```

)

The example at the bottom of this answer exhibits another way of implementing it.
(The `\Expandtimes`-variant in the example at the bottom of this answer does trigger a lot of `\csname`-expansion which in turn does affect allocation of memory related to the semantic nest size.)

E.g., if you wish the macro `\top` to be "hit" by `\expandafter` six times
while `\top`—before insertion of `\expandafter`—being the 16<sup>th</sup> token in the token-stream, you will need to have inserted six `\expandafter`-chains for bypassing 15 tokens. That's a lot of `\expandafter`.
(According to the formula, that would be 15·(2<sup>6</sup>-1) `\expandafter` = 945 `\expandafter`.)

Using the `\romannumeral\Expandtimes{<number K>}<token sequence>`-thingie, you can easily reduce to needing only one `\expandafter`-chain bypassing 15 tokens.
(According to the formula, that would be 15·(2<sup>1</sup>-1) `\expandafter` = 15 `\expandafter`.
That makes a difference of 930 `\expandafter`.)

This would look like this:

```tex
\expandafter\tokA
\expandafter\tokB
\expandafter\tokC
\expandafter\tokD
\expandafter\tokE
\expandafter\tokF
\expandafter\tokG
\expandafter\tokH
\expandafter\tokI
\expandafter\tokJ
\expandafter\tokK
\expandafter\tokL
\expandafter\tokM
\expandafter\tokN
\expandafter\tokO
\romannumeral\Expandtimes{6}\top
```

But 15 still is a lot of `\expandafter`.

By now only the trick of reducing to needing only one `\expandafter`-chain by using the `\romannumeral\Expandtimes{<number K>}`-thingie was applied.
Now there is only a single `\expandafter`-chain.
But that chain is long.

### Keep `\expandafter`-chains short by having TeX flip around macro arguments.

**Another trick for reducing the amount of `\expandafter` in your code
which can be applied in many (but not all!!) situations is keeping `\expandafter`-chains short simply by having TeX flip macro arguments around/simply by having TeX exchange macro arguments**:

```tex
\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%

\expandafter\exchange
\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\Expandtimes{6}\top
}{%
  \tokA\tokB\tokC\tokD\tokE
  \tokF\tokG\tokH\tokI\tokJ
  \tokK\tokL\tokM\tokN\tokO
}%
```

*(I wrote "but not all!!" because the trick of exchanging arguments cannot be applied in situations where the expansion-cascade triggered by `\Expandtimes` is intended to perform some brace-removal-hacks so that curly catcode1/2-braces in the result of the expansion-cascade are not balanced.)*

Now there is a reduction from needing 945 `\expandafter` to needing 2 `\expandafter`.
That makes a difference of 943 `\expandafter`.

But there is a subtle difference:

With the `\romannumeral\Expandtimes{6}`-approach bypassing 15 tokens by means of 15 `\expandafter`, only one expansion-step ("hitting" the first `\expandafter`of the `\expandafter`-chain) needs to be triggered for obtaining the 6-level-expansion of `\top`.

With the approach where the `\romannumeral\Expandtimes{6}`-thingie was combined with `\exchange`-ing arguments, two expansion-steps need to be triggered. One expansion-step is needed for "hitting" the first `\expandafter` of the `\expandafter`-chain consisting of only two `\expandafter`. Another one is needed for getting `\exchange` into doing its job of exchanging arguments.

If needed, you can once more apply good old `\romannumeral`-expansion for reducing to needing to trigger only one expansion step:

```tex
\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00
\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%

\romannumeral%<-\romannumeral gathers tokens for the <number>-quantity keeps expanding expandable tokens.
\expandafter\exchange
\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\Expandtimes{6}\top
}{\stopromannumeral
  %  After exchanging \stopromannumeral is right behind 
  %  \romannumeral and causes \romannumeral to
  %  terminate. It gets removed by \romannumeral which in turn does not
  %  deliver any tokens as \stopromannumeral denotes the value 0 is not a positive number.
  \tokA\tokB\tokC\tokD\tokE
  \tokF\tokG\tokH\tokI\tokJ
  \tokK\tokL\tokM\tokN\tokO
}%
```

With this technique the amount of `\expandafter` is independent from the amount of tokens that are to be "jumped" over.
This technique is useful when the amount of tokens to be "jumped" over is not predictable due to these tokens being delivered via macro-arguments.

Now an example where the tricks are combined for attaching tokens to a list that is stored as a macro whose name is to be given:

```tex
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%

\long\def\name#1#{\innername{#1}}%
\long\def\innername#1#2{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{#1}%
}%

\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00%

\def\Expandtimes#1{%
  \csname stopromannumeral\expandafter\Expandtimesloop
  \romannumeral\number\number#1 000D\endcsname
}%
\def\Expandtimesloop#1{%
  \if m\noexpand#1%
  \expandafter\expandafter\csname endcsname\expandafter\Expandtimesloop\fi
}%


% The most frugal and most boring thingie without \name and without \Expandtimes
% and without \romannumeral.
\long\def\appendtolist#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  {\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}%
  {%
    \expandafter\def\csname#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname,#2}%
  }%
}%

% Another thingie without \name and without \Expandtimes.
% This time a \romannumeral-trick is used for eliminating the need of
% having \csname launch two \expandafter-chains.
\long\def\otherappendtolist#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  {\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}%
  {%
    \expandafter\def\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\stopromannumeral
    \csname#1\endcsname,#2}%
  }%
}%

% One more thingie. This time \name and \exchange and \romannumeral-expansion
% are used. On the first glimpse it is confusing. Therefore it is one of my
% favorites.
\long\def\AndOneMoreAppendtolist#1#2{%
  \name\ifx{#1}\relax\expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  {\name\def{#1}{#2}}%
  {\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\romannumeral\name\stopromannumeral{#1},#2}}%
                                    {\name\expandafter\def\expandafter{#1}\expandafter}%
  }%
}%

% Yet another thingie.
% This time the helper-macro \Expandtimes is used for eliminating the need of
% having \csname launch two \expandafter-chains.
\long\def\yetotherappendtolist#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  {\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}%
  {%
    \expandafter\def\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\romannumeral\Expandtimes{2}\csname#1\endcsname,#2}%
  }%
}%

% A thingie where you can specify the level of expansion before appending.
\long\def\AppendLevelExpandedTolist#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\def
  \csname#1%
  \expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter{%
    \romannumeral
    \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
    {}{%
      \Expandtimes{2}\csname#1%
                  \expandafter\endcsname
                  \expandafter,%
                  \romannumeral
    }%
    \Expandtimes{#2}#3%
  }%
}%    

\tt

\appendtolist{mylist}{element1}

\name\string{mylist}\name\meaning{mylist}

\appendtolist{mylist}{element2}

\name\string{mylist}\name\meaning{mylist}

\otherappendtolist{mylist}{element3}

\name\string{mylist}\name\meaning{mylist}

\AndOneMoreAppendtolist{mylist}{element4}

\name\string{mylist}\name\meaning{mylist}

\yetotherappendtolist{mylist}{element5}

\name\string{mylist}\name\meaning{mylist}

\hrule

Now testing \string\Expandtimes:

\def\top{\first 0 }
\def\first{\second1 }
\def\second{\third2 }
\def\third{\fourth3 }
\def\fourth{\fifth4 }
\def\fifth{\sixth5 }
\def\sixth{6 }

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{0}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{1}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{2}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{3}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{4}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{5}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{6}\top

\expandafter\string\romannumeral\Expandtimes{7}\top

\hrule
    
Now testing \string\AppendLevelExpandedTolist:

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{myotherlist}{0}{\top}

\name\string{myotherlist}\name\meaning{myotherlist}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{myotherlist}{1}{\top}

\name\string{myotherlist}\name\meaning{myotherlist}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{myotherlist}{2}{\top}

\name\string{myotherlist}\name\meaning{myotherlist}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{myotherlist}{3}{\top}

\name\string{myotherlist}\name\meaning{myotherlist}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{myotherlist}{4}{\top}

\name\string{myotherlist}\name\meaning{myotherlist}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{myotherlist}{5}{\top}

\name\string{myotherlist}\name\meaning{myotherlist}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{myotherlist}{6}{\top}

\name\string{myotherlist}\name\meaning{myotherlist}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{myotherlist}{7}{\top}

\name\string{myotherlist}\name\meaning{myotherlist}

\bye
```

Comment: Such a great answer! I can't wait to go through it all. Thanks for the time you obviously spent composing this.

Answer (score 10):

Appending to an existing (parameterless) macro only requires one chain:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\foo<material to add>}
```

If the parameterless macro is called by name, so requiring `\csname`, the problem is a bit more complicated, requiring seven `\expandafter` tokens scattered in various places.

You can do it more easily with various methods.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appendtolist}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}
    {\@namedef{#1}{#2}}% not yet defined
    {\append@to@list{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\append@to@list}[2]{%
  \toks0=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}%
  \toks2={,#2}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{\the\toks0 \the\toks2}
}
\makeatother
```

With the triple `\expandafter` we reach after the `{` and expand twice `\csname #1\endcsname`; the first time we obtain the macro name, the second time its expansion. I use the fact that `\the\toks<n>` is just expanded once in an `\edef`.

You can do better, though. First define `\append@to@list` for the case

```
\append@to@list{\foo}{bar}
```

which is easy enough (and is what you already did)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\append@to@list}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\undefined
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\def#1{#2}}%
  {\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1,#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\appendtolist}[2]{%
  \expandafter\append@to@list\csname#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

Do you see the trick? The token obtained by expanding `\csname#1\endcsname` once is passed to `\append@to@list`.

This is very similar to the method used by `etoolbox` with its `\appto` and `\csappto` macros. However, whilst the code above doesn't rely on e-TeX primitives, the code in `etoolbox` does. With `etoolbox` it's very easy:

```
\newcommand{\appendtolist}[2]{%
  \ifcsundef{#1}
    {\csappto{#1}{#2}}
    {\csappto{#1}{,#2}}%
}
```

Last but not least: use `expl3`: no `\expandafter` at all, so no need to count them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendtolist}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = tokens to append
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { komar_list_#1_tl }
   {
    \tl_put_right:cn { komar_list_#1_tl } { ,#2 }
   }
   {
    \tl_new:c { komar_list_#1_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { komar_list_#1_tl } { #2 }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\uselist}{m}
 {% #1 = list name
  \tl_use:c { komar_list_#1_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\appendtolist{test}{a} \uselist{test}

\appendtolist{test}{b} \uselist{test}

\end{document}
```

For this case it would probably be better to use a clist variable, instead.

[image]

Comment: I feel like I am close to understanding this. I am not seeing how the macro token expanded from the macro name `\csname#1\endcsname` is passed to `\appendtomacro`. To me, it looks something like`\appendtomacro\#1{#2}`.

Comment: @macmadness86 `\expandafter\appendtomacro\csname foo\endcsname` is the same as `\appendtomacro\foo`, after `\expandafter` has performed its duty.

Comment: That is what I wrote above except I kept it generic with my `\foo` being `\#1`. So you can "pass" tokens that way? I was thinking passing would be like `\appendtomacro{\foo}`

Comment: @macmadness86 `\appendtomacro\foo` and `\appendtomacro{\foo}` are equivalent, if `\appendtomacro` has arguments.

Comment: It also looks to me like `\appendtomacro` is undefined. Where is its definition?

Comment: @macmadness86 Oh, sorry, I changed the name in the code, but not in the description; it should be `\append@to@list`

Comment: @egreg Within your first example, the `\appendtolist`-macro does process two arguments. I think having it process only one argument would be sufficient as both `\@namedef` and `\append@to@list` will "fetch" the second argument themselves if it is not delivered by the macro that calls them: `\newcommand{\appendtolist}[1]{\@ifundefined{#1}{\@namedef{#1}}{\append@to@list{#1}}}`.

Comment: @egreg Perhaps it should be pointed out that with your second example (the `\ifx`-comparison within the definition-text of `\append@to@list`) appending unbalanced `\else` or `\fi` might not yield the desired results as brace nesting is independent from `\if..\else..\fi`-nesting...  ;-) If such things can happen, perhaps a `\firstoftwo`...`\secondoftwo`-approach compined with `\romannumeral`-expansion might be an option.

Comment: @UlrichDiez That's just an example; I'd use higher level methods to begin with, such as the `etoolbox` one.

Answer (score 2):

I wish to add another answer because none of the answers provided so far (January 19, 2020, 16:10:00 UTC+0100) explicitly mentions the fact that expanding a macro yields halving the amount of consecutive hashes contained in its `⟨definition-text⟩`.

Assume you have defined your macro `\appendtolist` in a way where the macro holding the list gets expanded in order to have the expansion result form a portion of the new `⟨definition-text⟩`. During that expansion amounts of consecutive hashes stored as parts of the `⟨definition-text⟩` of the macro holding the list will be halved. This will happen whenever you append to the list:

```
\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\innerdfork#1d#2#3dd{#2}%
\def\dfork#1{\innerdfork#1{\firstoftwo}d{\secondoftwo}dd}%
\def\Expandtimes#1{0\expandafter\innerExp\expandafter{\expandafter}\romannumeral\number\number#1 000d}
\def\innerExp#1#2{\dfork{#2}{#1 }{\innerExp{#1#1\expandafter}}}

% A thingie where you can specify the level of expansion before appending.
\long\def\AppendLevelExpandedTolist#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\def
  \csname#1%
  \expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter{%
    \romannumeral
    \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
    {}{%
      \Expandtimes{2}\csname#1%
                  \expandafter\endcsname
                  \expandafter,%
                  \romannumeral
    }%
    \Expandtimes{#2}#3%
  }%
}%

\def\top{\first 0 }
\def\first{\second1 }
\def\second{\third2 }
\def\third{\fourth3 }
\def\fourth{\fifth4 }
\def\fifth{\sixth5 }
\def\sixth{6 } 

\def\mylist{SomethingWithHashes################}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{4}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{2}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{1}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{3}{\top}
\show\mylist

\bye
```

The terminal output with this approach is

```
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes########,\fourth 3 2 1 0 .
l.38     \show\mylist

? 
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes####,\fourth 3 2 1 0 ,\second 1 0 .
l.41     \show\mylist

? 
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes##,\fourth 3 2 1 0 ,\second 1 0 ,\first 0 .
l.44     \show\mylist

? 
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \mylist.
<to be read again>
```

Do you notice that the amount of hashes behind the phrase `SomethingWithHashes` is reduced successively?

Currently there are two ways of resolving this:

With traditional TeX you can put things into a token-register and then apply `\edef` to `\the⟨token-register⟩`.

With ε-TeX-extensions available you can use `\unexpanded{...}` instead of `\the⟨token-register⟩`.

The reason is:

Both with `\edef⟨macro⟩{\the⟨token-register⟩}` and with `\edef⟨macro⟩{\unexpanded{⟨stuff where hashes shall not appear reduced⟩}}` hashes get doubled and further expansion gets suppressed.

With ε-TeX-extensions not available you can do something like this:

```
\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
\def\innerdfork#1d#2#3dd{#2}%
\def\dfork#1{\innerdfork#1{\firstoftwo}d{\secondoftwo}dd}%
\def\Expandtimes#1{0\expandafter\innerExp\expandafter{\expandafter}\romannumeral\number\number#1 000d}
\def\innerExp#1#2{\dfork{#2}{#1 }{\innerExp{#1#1\expandafter}}}

\newtoks\myscratchtoks

% A thingie where you can specify the level of expansion before appending.
\long\def\AppendLevelExpandedTolist#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\myscratchtoks\expandafter{\the\myscratchtoks}%
  }{%
    \myscratchtoks\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
      {}{%
        \Expandtimes{2}\csname#1%
                    \expandafter\endcsname
                    \expandafter,%
                    \romannumeral
      }%
      \Expandtimes{#2}#3%
    }%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{\the\myscratchtoks}%
  }%
}%

\def\top{\first 0 }
\def\first{\second1 }
\def\second{\third2 }
\def\third{\fourth3 }
\def\fourth{\fifth4 }
\def\fifth{\sixth5 }
\def\sixth{6 } 

\def\mylist{SomethingWithHashes################}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{4}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{2}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{1}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{3}{\top}
\show\mylist

\bye
```

The terminal output is:

```
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes################,\fourth 3 2 1 0 .
l.43     \show\mylist

? 
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes################,\fourth 3 2 1 0 ,\second 1 0 .
l.46     \show\mylist

? 
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes################,\fourth 3 2 1 0 ,\second 1 0 ,\first 0 .
l.49     \show\mylist

? 
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes################,\fourth 3 2 1 0 ,\second 1 0 ,\first 0 ,\
third 2 1 0 .
l.52     \show\mylist
```

With this approach hashes are not reduced.

With ε-TeX-extensions available you can do something like this:

```
\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\innerdfork#1d#2#3dd{#2}%
\def\dfork#1{\innerdfork#1{\firstoftwo}d{\secondoftwo}dd}%
\def\Expandtimes#1{0\expandafter\innerExp\expandafter{\expandafter}\romannumeral\number\number#1 000d}
\def\innerExp#1#2{\dfork{#2}{#1 }{\innerExp{#1#1\expandafter}}}

% A thingie where you can specify the level of expansion before appending.
\long\def\AppendLevelExpandedTolist#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
    {}{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\romannumeral\Expandtimes{2}\csname#1\endcsname,}%
    }%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\romannumeral\Expandtimes{#2}#3}%
  }%
}%

\def\top{\first 0 }
\def\first{\second1 }
\def\second{\third2 }
\def\third{\fourth3 }
\def\fourth{\fifth4 }
\def\fifth{\sixth5 }
\def\sixth{6 } 

\def\mylist{SomethingWithHashes################}

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{4}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{2}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{1}{\top}
\show\mylist

\AppendLevelExpandedTolist{mylist}{3}{\top}
\show\mylist

\bye
```

The terminal output is:

```
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes################,\fourth 3 2 1 0 .
l.31     \show\mylist

? 
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes################,\fourth 3 2 1 0 ,\second 1 0 .
l.34     \show\mylist

? 
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes################,\fourth 3 2 1 0 ,\second 1 0 ,\first 0 .
l.37     \show\mylist

? 
> \mylist=macro:
->SomethingWithHashes################,\fourth 3 2 1 0 ,\second 1 0 ,\first 0 ,\
third 2 1 0 .
l.40     \show\mylist
```

With this approach hashes are not reduced.