# Formal term for LaTeX shorthand

Tags: arguments, terminology

It is possible in LaTeX to write expressions like `\frac12`, which should be equivalent to expressions like `\frac{1}{2}`. Is there a formal term for the first form of notation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The form `\frac12` works because the argument to an undelimited TeX macro (like `\frac`) is either a single token (`1` is a single token, for example) or, a group of tokens delimited by `{...}`, in which case the outer braces are removed. That's why both forms are equivalent. However there isn't a special name to one of them...

Comment: Braces for macro arguments in TeX work similar to braces for statements in languages like C or JavaScript: they just group several of them to a single unit. While always using braces is generally considered a good coding style in LaTeX, as it improves readability, from the compiler's perspective the braces in `\frac{1}{2}` are just "more work to do", because it's unnecessary to group a single token.

Comment: @siracusa I am not agree at all. I remember that a time ago David Carlisle said to me that if removing braces there is a chance to break math in multiple lines. That's why the use of braces is *always* a good practise.

Comment: @manooooh Can you elaborate on how it would break?

Comment: @siracusa I am not finding the fragment where (I believe) David said that. Let's wait his advice or instead decline my suggestion.

Comment: @manooooh that is a different thing.  `${ 1 = 0 }$` the braces act essentially like an implicit `\hbox` and prevent linebreaking and space stretching, but braces used as macro argument delimiters are a different thing entirely.

Comment: @siracusa ^^^^^^

Comment: For the curious, the braces in @DavidCarlisle's example `${ 1 = 0 }$` delimit what Knuth calls a *subformula*, and indeed they have consequences I didn't anticipate before reading about them in the TeXbook!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so what are the differences if `\frac12` will not prevent linebreaking nor space stretching?

Comment: @manooooh none at all to latex, at the tex layer it is impossible to detect if a single token macro argument is used with braces. But to human readers, syntax checkers and highlighters and latex to - whatever convertors, it is far better to stick to the documented syntax.

Comment: With `\frac12` you have a control word token `\frac` triggering the processing of two braceless undelimited arguments. With `\frac{1}2` you have a control word token `\frac` triggering the processing of an undelimted  argument nested in braces and a braceless undelimited argument. With `\frac1{2}` you have a control word token `\frac` triggering the processing of a braceless undelimted  argument and an undelimited argument nested in braces. With `\frac{1}{2}` you have a control word token `\frac` triggering the processing of two undelimited arguments, each of them nested in braces.

Comment: For the interested: I elaborated in detail on the ways in which (La)TeX processes arguments in the discussion [How does TeX look for delimited arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438600/118714) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

---

This is just part of the normal way TeX absorbs non-delimited macro arguments. If you define

```
\def\foo#1{Something using #1 (or not).}
```

or equivalently

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{Something using #1 (or not).}
```

when `\foo` is expanded, it absorbs the next token or balanced group in the input stream as its argument (which is available as `#1` in the definition).
Assuming normal category codes

- a token is a single character (except `\`, `{`, `}`, `%` or a space or newline (since those are ignored)) or a command sequence (something starting with `\`),
- a balanced group starts with `{` and ends with the first `}` that does not belong to a different group (that started later). The braces are stripped from the group upon absorption (that is, `#1` does not contain them).

This is why `\foo x` and `\foo{x}`, `\newcommand{\foo}` and `\newcommand\foo` or `\frac 12`, `\frac{1}{2}`, `\frac{1}2` and `\frac1 2` are equivalent.

It is good practice to choose the version that is clearest, which usually means using a group. Personally, I explicitly omit the group in cases where I *have to* input a single token, like `\newcommand\foo`.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth adding that distinguishing between single-token arguments and arguments in braces is more explicit in LaTeX3/`expl3`. By convention, every `expl3` macro name should end in `:` followed by a sequence of letters, called argument specifiers, each reflecting the type of the corresponding argument.

Beside many others we have

- `n` for braced-group or single-token arguments, and
- `N` for single-token arguments only, usually macro/function names or variable names.

Those specifiers still don't change the way (La)TeX processes the individual arguments, but it gives a hint to the user about how the arguments are used inside the macro.

For example, the `l3tl` package provides two functions `\tl_if_empty:nTF` and `\tl_if_empty:NTF`. While both functions check if a token list is empty and execute code conditionally, the former is expected to be called with a braced group of tokens, where the latter expects a token list variable that is first expanded before the test is performed on its contents.