# Simple implementation of the abs function by getting rid of or by consuming the "-"?

Tags: strings, text-manipulation

I wish to build a (simple) implementation of abs.
I tried `\FPabs` but I get a lot of zeros after the decimal point. I could get rid of them with the FP round function, but I don't know the number of decimals I will have.

I think a string manipulation approach is better. I could use the `xstring` package to get rid of the minus as in -12.3 to get 12.3 but a full package just for that ...

Is there a simple way to get rid or consume the "-" of "-12.3" for instance to get "12.3" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define `\gobbleminus` by this way:

```
\def\gobbleminus#1{\ifx-#1\else#1\fi}

%test:
\gobbleminus -12

\gobbleminus 1234

\gobbleminus .24
```

Comment: Elegant way to get rid of the "-" as looked for !

Answer (score 11):

You could use xfp (the package is very short, it contains only two definitions to create wrappers around `\fp_eval:n` and `\int_eval:n`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

\fpeval{abs(-12.3)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is expandable, that means you can fed it to `\num` for formatting. Here I change the period to a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,siunitx}

\sisetup{locale=DE}
\begin{document}

\num{\fpeval{abs(-12.3)}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, I immediately adopted before wipet’s solution came out. I will retain it for other functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you get a LaTeX3 solution by one of the experts in no time and I really don't think that a string-based solution is the best you can do here, but while you wait here is a simple, argument-based solution.

The solution is not expandable, which might be a bit of deal-breaker depending on what you want to do (but: see below).

The main idea is to use delimited arguments ([How does TeX look for delimited arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438359/35864)) to strip characters from a string. In order not to run into trouble here, we first check whether the characters are actually present.

`\ifstrstartswith` works by defining a helper macro `\fstr@ifstrstartswith@i` that grabs arguments as follows

```
#1<characters to find>#2&
```

if we now pass a string to `\fstr@ifstrstartswith@i` that starts with `<characters to find>`, TeX's argument parse rules make `#1` come up empty. In order to avoid errors, we always call `\fstr@ifstrstartswith@i` with `\fstr@ifstrstartswith@i <string><characters to find>&`. This means that even if `<string>` does not contain `<characters to find>` at all, we still have called the macro with the right argument signature.

The characters stripping now works similarly. We check that `<string>` actually starts with `<characters to remove>` and then apply a helper macro `\fstr@stripfromstart@i` with signature

```
<characters to remove>#1&
```

which then strips off the `<characters to remove>` from the beginning of `<string>` when called as `\fstr@stripfromstart@i <string>&`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% {<characters to find>}{<string>}
\newrobustcmd*{\ifstrstartswith}[2]{%
  \def\fstr@ifstrstartswith@i##1#1##2&{%
    \ifblank{##1}}%
  \fstr@ifstrstartswith@i#2#1&}

% {<characters to remove>}{<string>}
\newrobustcmd*{\stripfromstart}[2]{%
  \def\fstr@stripfromstart@i#1##1&{##1}%
  \ifstrstartswith{#1}{#2}
    {\fstr@stripfromstart@i#2&}
    {#2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\mysimpleabs}{\stripfromstart{-}}

\begin{document}
\mysimpleabs{4.5}

\mysimpleabs{-4.5}
\end{document}
```

[image: 4.5//4.5]

Of course you don't want to try `\mysimpleabs{-4.5-5}` or `\mysimpleabs{-4.5+5}`.

---

*edit* Come to think of it, we can make this expandable if we hard-code the `-`. Still, string manipulation does not strike me as the best way to deal with this.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fstr@ifstrstartswithminus@i}{} % just to reserve the name
\def\fstr@ifstrstartswithminus@i#1-#2&{\ifblank{#1}}

\newcommand*{\ifstrstartswithminus}[1]{%
  \fstr@ifstrstartswithminus@i#1-&}

\newcommand*{\fstr@stripminusfromstart@i}{} % just to reserve the name
\def\fstr@stripminusfromstart@i-#1&{#1}

\newcommand*{\stripminusfromstart}[1]{%
  \ifstrstartswithminus{#1}
    {\fstr@stripminusfromstart@i#1&}
    {#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\mysimpleabs}{\stripminusfromstart}

\begin{document}
\mysimpleabs{4.5}

\mysimpleabs{-4.5}

\edef\foo{\mysimpleabs{12.3}}
\meaning\foo

\edef\foo{\mysimpleabs{-12.3}}
\meaning\foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you think a string approach shouldn't be used here ? What are the drawbacks ?

Comment: @user1771398 The most obvious problem is that it doesn't produce the mathematically correct result for more complex terms like `\mysimpleabs{-4.5-5}`. Plus it feels a bit intellectually dishonest to use string operations to manipulate numbers. But if you can guarantee that you will only ever input a single number which either does or does not start with `-` the approach might still work well enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the thing you're removing the minus from starts with a minus or a digit, then the *old school* way of doing this would be

```
\makeatletter
\def\gobbleminus#1{\ifnum#17<\z@ \@firstoftwo\fi #1}
\makeatother
```

e.g.

```
\gobbleminus 12.3    % Expands to 12.3
\gobbleminus -12.3   % Expands to 12.3
\gobbleminus -0.1000 % Expands to 0.1000
```

If your data is being generated by expanding something, you will of course need to make sure it gets sufficiently expanded before letting \gobbleminus act on it.

Another catch is that

```
\gobbleminus .123    % Raises error
```

since . is not a minus or digit. Though it occurs to me that one could make it tolerate this as well, by changing the definition to

```
\makeatletter
\def\gobbleminus#1{\ifdim#17pt<\z@ \@firstoftwo\fi #1}
\makeatother
```