# Add optional parameter to def

Tags: parameters, definition

So I was looking for a way to do something in latex, and I ran across the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo{1}
\def\bar#1 #2{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\foo {}#1}
    \let\next\bar%
    \ifx#2\relax%
    \let\next\relax%
    \fi%
    \next#2%
}
\bar 2 3 4 \relax

\begin{document}
    \foo
\end{document}
```

Basically what it does is it starts with `foo` equal to `1` and it concatenates the numbers `2`, `3`, `4` afterwards and you end up with it outputting `1234`.

I understand how *most* of this is working, but I'm confused on two different fronts (which are probably the same front?) and so I was wondering if someone could explain what's happening. At the end I'll mention what I'm *trying* to do, to hopefully show motivation as to why I'm asking.

Basically, my first confusion has to do with: `\def\bar#1 #2`. Normally I thought you had to add an optional parameter like `\def\bar[2]{#1 #2}` or something, but it seems like this is doing something differently? Is `#1 #2` basically saying `2` is set as `#1` then there's a space and then `3 4` is set as `#2`?

My second confusion is with the term `\next`. This is also in conjunction with how this is looping because it seems like it shouldn't? I'm assuming it's the `\next` operator that's doing it, so I was wondering how this works.

My motivating question comes from me wanting to do something like this, but to stop after some number. So for example, I want to be able to call: `\bar{4} 2 3 4 5 6 7\relax` and have the output be `1234` (so it stops when it hits `4`). Since I'm not understanding how the looping is happening and how `\def` is working, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have one unwanted space in your macro at the end of the line 5, but next four lines have percent character irrelevantly. Maybe, you want to start to read something about how TeX works, for example http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\next` is not a predefined operator. It's just a scratch control sequence that gets redefined several times during the loop.

What happens when `\bar` is called (by the way it's a bad name, because `\bar` *is* a predefined control sequence that's used for a math accent)?

Its definition has parameter text `#1 #2`, which means that TeX will absorb everything until the first space token, assigning it to the parameter `#1` and then a further token or braced list of tokens, assigning it to the parameter `#2`.

Next a long string of `\expandafter` tokens is executed. Let's say you have the input `\bar 2 3 4 \relax`.

In this case `#1` is `2` and `#2` is `3`. Then TeX will do

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\foo {}2}
```

Each `\expandafter` tokens is touched in turns and the last one causes `\foo` to be expanded to its current meaning, so you get

```
\def\foo{1{}2}
```

Such definition is stored and then the next line is looked at, so `\next` is assigned the same meaning as `\bar`. Then `#2` is compared to `\relax`; in this case the test returns false, because `#2` is `3`, so the text up to `\fi` is skipped over. It remains

```
\next#2
```

so now TeX is confronted with

```
\bar3 4 \relax
```

The same thing now happens twice, so we arrive at

```
\def\foo{1{}2{}3{}4}
```

but now there's a difference, because `#2` now is `\relax`. So the `\ifx` test returns true and TeX does `\let\next\relax`, so the last instruction becomes

```
\relax\relax
```

and the loop ends.

Not a particularly good way to do the task, but it works. By the way, a `%` is missing at the end of the `\expandafter` line and there are redundant ones in the next two lines.

If you want to stop the loop earlier you need to modify the macros and introduce a counter to index the number of runs.

Maybe a more modern loop is what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__aram_addto_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\aramaddto}{mom}
 {
  % first split the final argument at spaces (here ~ stands for a space)
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__aram_addto_seq { ~ } { #3 }
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {% no optional argument, add everything
    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \exp_not:V #1 \seq_use:Nn \l__aram_addto_seq { } }
   }
   {% optional argument, only add as many items as required
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__aram_addto_seq
     {% ##1 is the current index, ##2 is the item
      \int_compare:nTF { ##1 < #2 }
       {% still wanting to add
        \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { ##2 }
       }
       {% flush
        \seq_map_break:
       }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\fooA}{1}

\aramaddto\fooA{2 3 4}

Should print 1234: \fooA

\newcommand{\fooB}{1}

\aramaddto\fooB[4]{2 3 4 5 6}

Should print 1234: \fooB

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

After the comments, here's a way how to accomplish the aim, that is, input a list of numbers and multiplying them all, with the option to stop when one of the numbers is greater than a stated upper bound.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\genfactorial}{om}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \aram_genfactorial:en { \clist_item:nn { #2 } { -1 } } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \aram_genfactorial:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__aram_genfactorial_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aram_genfactorial:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__aram_genfactorial_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { ##1 <= #1 }
     { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__aram_genfactorial_seq { ##1 } }
     { \clist_map_break: }
   }
  \fp_eval:n { \seq_use:Nn \l__aram_genfactorial_seq { * } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \aram_genfactorial:nn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\genfactorial{1,2,3,4}

\genfactorial[45]{1,2,3,4,5,6,45,67,89}

\end{document}
```

Using a comma separated list seems better than separating items with spaces.

[image]

### Update

With `expl3` released 2021-05-07, we can make the above fully expandable, due to the new `\clist_map_tokens:nn` function.

The check is made with `0` as default optional argument, assuming that the input will consist of positive numbers.

The given input is mapped item by item and `*<item>` is appended, but the `<item>` is transformed into 1 if the optional argument is 0 or the upper bound is exceeded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\genfactorial}{O{0}m}
 {
  \aram_genfactorial:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \aram_genfactorial:nn
 {
  \fp_eval:n 
   {
    1
    \clist_map_tokens:nn { #2 } { \__aram_genfactorial:nn { #1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__aram_genfactorial:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 0 }
   {% no bound
    * #2
   }
   {% #1 is the upper bound
    \int_compare:nTF { #2 <= #1 } { * #2 } { * 1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\genfactorial{1,2,3,4}

\genfactorial[4]{1,2,3,4,5,6,45,67,89}

\genfactorial[7]{1,2,3,4,5,6,45,67,89}

\genfactorial[45]{1,2,3,4,5,6,45,67,89}

\edef\test{\genfactorial{1,2,3,4,5,6,45,67,89}}\test

\end{document}
```

The last line shows that the function is indeed fully expandable.

[image]

Comment: That makes more sense. (I know `bar` is used in math, but wanted to keep consistent with the example. And since `def` overwrites things anyways, it wasn't to big of a problem for MWE)

I like your new method but it brings up so many new questions. Is there documentation for the "new way" of doing things? (I want to take these numbers, put a multiplication sign between them and then plug it into the package `fp` in order to create a factorial operator. )

Comment: Maybe my document is misbehaving, but the above doesn't work when I get into two digit numbers: `\aramaddto\fooB[45]{2 3 4 5 6 45 67 89}` is printing out all of `123456456789` instead of stopping at `45`?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I think `int_compare` should be `##2 < #2` ? Is that correct?

Comment: @AramPapazian It seems I misunderstood your target: so the optional number is the upper bound after which the collection should stop, not the number of items to collect/

Comment: @AramPapazian I added code that does what you seem to want.

Comment: Yup! I guess maybe I hadn't explained correctly. Sorry about that. This looks perfect! Thank you for the help <3 I need to learn latex3. It seems super powerful

Answer (score 0):

The looping is more of an recursion. It eats two arguments at a time.

First pass: it sees `\bar 2 3`; here `#1->2` and `#2->3`. The number 2 is concatenated to `\foo`, `\next` is set to be `\bar` (since `#2` is not `\relax`).

Then it is told to process `\next #2` which is the same as `\bar 3`. But that is missing one argument! So it looks for the next argument and in effect you process `\bar 3 4`. You run though the same thing again, and the next time, however, you end up processing `\bar 4 relax`.

This time, after plopping `4` into `\foo`, in the `\ifx` you see that `#2` is `\relax`, so `\next` is told to no longer be `\bar`. And so the recursion stops.

Comment: Ooo awesome. That helps me understand the recursion. Any idea for `\def` and how it's being constructed since it's nonstandard? In addition to how I might be able to pass in an additional argument?

Comment: @AramPapazian `\def` is standard. There is nothing else which is more standard.

Comment: @AramPapazian: the format of `\def` uses delimited arguments. [Here's a decent guide to how this and some related things work.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438600/119)