# Why do nameref package zap the ending dot in \label and how to avoid this zap locally?

Tags: hyperref, definition, nameref

So, I'm hacking something related to `nameref` and during the hacking, I find on the beginning of page 3 of the `nameref` manual on my computer (dated 2016/05/21) that

> We redefine `\label` so that it also writes the name of the current section to the .aux file; **if the name ends in a dot, we zap it**.

I checked the [newest documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/nameref.pdf) of `nameref` in the CTAN and this sentence is still there. Actually, I don't want this functionality to work for my own `\newcounter` since it does end with a dot.

So, my questions are

1. Why do they do something like **if the name ends in a dot, we zap it**?
2. Is there a good way to hack this locally to make `\label` aware of the ending dot? Why locally? I'm assuming that there exists a good reason for the first question so that I'm not recommended to erase this entirely.
3. Actually I understand that this functionality is realized by this definition on the same page

   `\def\NR@strip@period#1.\ltx@empty#2\@nil{#1}`

   But, I'm quite confused by its use since this `\def` is followed by three commands in a row while the usual one looks just like `\def\newcommand<argument>\oldcommand`. So, can anyone explain how this line works to me? Or maybe point to me some reference. So that I can myself figure out the hacking.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438359/how-does-tex-look-for-delimited-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why that way? it's all a long time ago but while some styles treat the title as a sentence and have

**Introduction.**
Blah blah...

in a generated reference you would want it to say "in the Introduction we describe..  never "in the Introduction. we describe ....`  so you need the . to go.

Unlike `\newcommand` the primitve `\def` allows *delimited arguments* that end at a specied token.

If you go

```
\def\zz#1.{the argument is #1}
```

then `\zz` will take as argument everything up to the first `.` so

`\zz The Introduction.`

would produce `the argument is The Introduction`  with no .  so that's almost what is wanted except if the section title didn't have a . this would give a low level error that the argument never ended, so the trick is to use a form such as

```
\def\zz#1.#2\relax{#1}
```

and always supply the `.` and `\relax`

now if `#1` is the argument from `\section` then

```
\zz#1.\relax
```

can be called as

```
\zz The Introduction..\relax
```

now we get #1 is The Introduction and #2 is . which is discarded

and if there was no . in the original the call is

```
\zz The Introduction.\relax
```

and here again #1 is The Introduction and now #2 is empty and not used.

`\NR@strip@period` is a slightly more complicated version of this `\zz` idea.