# Logical markup for math symbols/variables, alternative to \newcommand

Tags: macros, naming, variable, markup

I would like to use markup for any math symbols/variables (Sorry, I'm not sure what is the correct terminology here). The reason is to make late changes of the naming convention easier by just adjusting in one place.
The following minimal example shows what I want to do and also the limitation of using \newcommand as it does not allow to use numbers in the macro name. If the commented line is compiled it will throw an error, however numbers are needed to describe some variables as there will be multiple ones just different by the number.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\asteer}{a_{steer}}
\newcommand{\awheelfl}{a_{Wheel,FL}}
\newcommand{\awheelfr}{a_{Wheel,FR}}
%\newcommand{\rthrottle5}{r_{Throttle,q5}}
\begin{equation}
    a_{Steer} = a_{Wheel,FL} - a_{Wheel,FR}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \asteer = \awheelfl - \awheelfr
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I found a solution here: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linmacnames (#2), however I am wondering if there is a better solution to that. Maybe \newcommand doesn't need to be used for this at all.

Cheers,
Lukas

Comment: The problem is not only that you usually can't define macros with numbers in them with `\newcommand`, you also can't use/call them like normal macros even if you do manage to define them: `\rthrottle5` would just be interpreted as `\rthrottle 5` (i.e. `\rthrottle` and then a `5`). You could define your own 'replacement' for `\newcommand` that allows numbers in command names, but those commands would have to be called differently. The usual recommendation is just to let the numbers go and try Roman numerals or words, but you could also use an argument if that makes sense.

Comment: Solution number #3 from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linmacnames is one of the more dangerous ones. I certainly would not recommend you do this in a more complex document. Especially if you have to turn more numbers into letters.

Comment: Command arguments seem to be a sensible solution here, as @moewe mentioned. Something like `\awheel{FL}`, `\awheel{FR}`, `\rthrottle{5}` with `#1` in the body of the command at the position of FL/FR/5.

Comment: @moewe: Sorry I accidentaly posted the wrong number. I was thinking of #2 beeing a practical but not very understandable solution.

Comment: Number 2 is what I thought of when I talked about a 'replacement' for `\newcommand` and calling the resulting macros differently (see also jfbu's answer below, you essentially have a call wrapper: instead of `\foo5` you call `\usename{foo5}`). If you must have numbers and can't use an argument then that would be my preferred solution. But before you look into this I would urge you to look into commands with arguments or to drop the number in the macro name.

Comment: I could use arguments although it is not as nice as typing `\rthrotle5`. The only downside I can see now is if I wanted to do e.g. `\rthrottleq5static`, however I am not sure yet if that might be needed. For this the replacement of `\newcommand` looks more universal to mee. Could you please point out why it's your least favourite solution?

Comment: It's my least favourite of the three options: (1) Don't use digits in command names. (2) Use an optional argument for numbers (does not make sense in all situations, but could be useful for generic subscripts). (3) Use something like `\usename`/`\@nameuse`. But they are pretty close. It is definitely better than some of the other options suggested in https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linmacnames. I have no technical objection to `\usename`, it's just that I'm used to writing `\foo`, so using `\usename{foo5}` for some macros is somewhat inconsistent ... but that's all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was curious if there's a technical reason/best practice or if it's more down to personal preference.

Comment: Under normal circumstances spaces behind the control word `\foo` do not get tokenized while spaces behind token sequences like `\usename{foo5}` (or `\@nameuse{foo5}` or `\name{foo5}`) do get tokenized as space-tokens. Besides this, things might turn out confusing when doing things like `\def\foo{fo}\def\bar{o}\usename{\foo\bar5}`. Also I recommend to not use `\csname..\endcsname`-wrappers like `\usename/\name/\@nameuse` with obscure `\endcsname` in the argument—things like `\@nameuse{TeX\expandafter\endcsname\@gobble}` and `\@nameuse{TeX\endcsname\csname TeX}`  might be inscrutable . ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use glossaries. This gives you the additional benefit to build list of symbols.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{asteer}
{%
  name={$a_{\mathrm{steer}}$},
  text={a_{\mathrm{steer}}},
  description={whatever},
  sort={a}
}

\newglossaryentry{awheelfl}
{%
  name={$a_{\mathrm{Wheel,FL}}$},
  text={a_{\mathrm{Wheel,FL}}},
  description={whatever},
  sort={a}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \gls{asteer} = \gls{awheelfl}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case wouldn't `\scriptscriptstyle` look better?

Comment: @daleif the look is up-to the user.

Comment: Who might not know about scriptscriptstyle

Comment: I like the benefit of automatic list of symbols hence I mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newname[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname}

\newcommand\usename[1]{\@nameuse{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newname{a1}{this is a1}

\usename{a1}

% \newname{a1}{this is a1}% LaTeX Error: Command \a1 already defined.

\newname{a2}[3]{this is a2, it gets arguments #1, #2, #3}

\usename{a2}{aa}{bbb}{cccc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I realize now this is quite close to `#2` of posted link. But it is better because it allows the star-variant to be defined too, as weel as macros with optional arguments.

---

#### updated

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newname[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname}

\newcommand\usename[1]{\@nameuse{#1}}

\newcommand\ZZZ{}% check not defined
\def\ZZZ#1#{\@nameuse{ZZZ#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newname{a1}{this is a1}

\usename{a1}

% \newname{a1}{this is a1}% LaTeX Error: Command \a1 already defined.

\newname{a2}[3]{this is a2, it gets arguments #1, #2, #3}

\usename{a2}{aa}{bbb}{cccc}

\newname{ZZZ1}{this is ZZZ1, it has no arguments, braces mandatory}
\newname{ZZZ2}{this is ZZZ2, it has no arguments, braces mandatory}
\newname{ZZZ---999}[2]{this is ZZZ-\mbox{}-\mbox{}-999 with arguments #1 and #2}


\ZZZ1{}

\ZZZ2{}

\ZZZ---999{aaaa}{bbbb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why passing `#1` from `\usename` to `\@nameuse` instead of  `\let\usename=\@nameuse` or `\newcommand*\usename{\@nameuse}`?

Comment: @UlrichDiez you are right `\let\usename=\@nameuse` is better. I wrote this in jest, not expecting it to be used by anyone, hopefully they will take this comment into account.

Answer (score 0):

[In my answer to the question "Define a control sequence after that a space matters"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338784/118714) I elaborated on a macro `\name` which is to be used as follows:

`\name <tokens without braces>{<name of Control Sequence Token>}`
→ `<tokens without braces>\ControlSequenceToken`

You can use the `\name`-macro both for defining and for calling macros.

---

Here comes the implementation:

```
\newcommand\name{}%
\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
```

---

This is the way of using `\name` for **defining** macros:

Example 1:

`\name\newcommand{rthrottle5}` yields:
`\newcommand\rthrottle5`, thus you can, e.g., do:

`\name\newcommand{rthrottle5}{r_{Throttle,q5}}`
→ `\newcommand\rthrottle5{r_{Throttle,q5}}`

Example 2:

`\name\global\long\def{foo}` yields:
`\global\long\def\foo`, thus you can, e.g., do:

`\name\global\long\def{foo}#1#2{foo's arg1: #1; foo's arg2: #2.}`
→ `\global\long\def\foo#1#2{foo's arg1: #1; foo's arg2: #2.}`

---

Example 3:

This is the way of using `\name` for **calling** macros:
Just leave the `<tokens without braces>`-argument empty:

`\name{rthrottle5}`
→ `\rthrottle5`

---

The `<tokens without braces>`-argument can also consist of a sequence of some more calls of the `name`-macro.

Example 4:

`\name\name\let{foo}={bar}`
→ `\name\let\foo={bar}`
→ `\let\foo=\bar`

Example 5:

`\name\name\name\futurelet{foo}{bar}{baz}`
→`\name\name\futurelet\foo{bar}{baz}`
→`\name\futurelet\foo\bar{baz}`
→`\futurelet\foo\bar\baz`

---

Using the `\name`-macro  within your example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand\name{}%
\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%

\begin{document}
\name\newcommand{asteer}{a_{Steer}}
\name\newcommand{awheelfl}{a_{Wheel,FL}}
\name\newcommand{awheelfr}{a_{Wheel,FR}}
\name\newcommand{rthrottle5}{r_{Throttle,q5}}
\begin{equation}
    a_{Steer} + r_{Throttle,q5} = a_{Wheel,FL} - a_{Wheel,FR} + r_{Throttle,q5}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \name{asteer} + \name{rthrottle5} = \name{awheelfl} - \name{awheelfr} + \name{rthrottle5}
\end{equation}

Or. if you like:

\begin{equation}
    \name\name\name\name\name%
    {asteer} + {rthrottle5} = {awheelfl} - {awheelfr} + {rthrottle5}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]