# Missing \endcsname inserted (repost with MWE)

Tags: macros, errors, overleaf

Reposting as a MWE, hopefully this is minimal enough. Sorry if there's anything irrelevant.

I'm getting this error on the final '}' just before the end:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@questions 
l.26 }
      
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

here's the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setq[3]{%
    \global\@namedef{qa:#1.#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother
\newtotcounter{questions}
\newcommand\newq[4]{%
    \setq{\value{questions}}{Number}{\value{questions}}
    \setq{\value{questions}}{Date}{#1}
    \setq{\value{questions}}{Time}{#2}
    \setq{\value{questions}}{Question}{#3}
    \setq{\value{questions}}{Answer}{#4}
    \stepcounter{questions}
}

\newq{268}%
{10:25}%
{Can you create a latex project with multiple documents?}%
{Yes, at least you can in Overleaf. You click on the menu in the top-left, and change main document to the tex file you want to compile.%
}

\end{document}
```

I'm using overleaf if that changes anything.
Any optimisations I can make to the code not-related to the error is also appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT: Changed value to arabic, that's removed the endcsname error, but now I have a general compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

While the value of the `questions`-counter is `0` the sequence `\setq{\arabic{questions}}{Number}{\arabic{questions}}` yields defining the control-word-token `\qa:0.Number` to deliver the token-sequence `\arabic{questions}`.
That token-sequence in turn will be carried out/expanded not at the time of defining but at the time right after using/expanding the control-word `\qa:0.Number`, yielding
the value of the `question`-counter current not at the time of defining but at the time of using/expanding the control-word `\qa:0.Number`.
You probably wish to have the sequence `\arabic{questions}` expanded at the time of defining `\qa:0.Number`.

Instead of `\arabic{questions}` I use `\number\value{questions}` because with the latter you need only one `\expandafter`-chain for triggering expansion until obtaining the value while with the further you need four `\expandafter`-chains:

```
 \arabic=macro:
#1->\expandafter \@arabic \csname c@#1\endcsname .
l.16 \show\arabic
                 
? i
insert> \show\@arabic
> \@arabic=macro:
#1->\number #1.
<insert>   \makeatletter\show\@arabic
                                     
l.16 \show\arabic
```

The first `\expandafter`-chain to obtain `\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@questions\endcsname` from `\arabic{questions}`.

The second `\expandafter`-chain to obtain `\@arabic\c@questions` from `\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@questions\endcsname`.

The third `\expandafter`-chain to obtain `\number\c@questions` from `\@arabic\c@questions`.

The fourth `\expandafter`-chain to obtain the sequence of decimal digits denoting the value of the `\count`-register `\c@questions` from `\number\c@questions`.

On my system the following MWE compiles without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{totcount}
% \usepackage{pgffor}


\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand\setq[3]{%
    \global\csname @namedef\endcsname{qa:#1.#2}{#3}%
}
\newtotcounter{questions}
\newcommand\newq[4]{%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\number\value{questions}}{\setq{\arabic{questions}}{Number}}%
    \setq{\arabic{questions}}{Date}{#1}%
    \setq{\arabic{questions}}{Time}{#2}%
    \setq{\arabic{questions}}{Question}{#3}%
    \setq{\arabic{questions}}{Answer}{#4}%
    \stepcounter{questions}%
}

\newq{268}%
{10:25}%
{Can you create a latex project with multiple documents?}%
{Yes, at least you can in Overleaf. You click on the menu in the top-left, and change main document to the tex file you want to compile.%
}

\begin{document}

\par\noindent
\csname qa:0.Number\endcsname\\
\csname qa:0.Date\endcsname\\
\csname qa:0.Time\endcsname\\
\csname qa:0.Question\endcsname\\
\csname qa:0.Answer\endcsname

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might be interested in the `\name`-macro. I elaborated on the `\name`-macro in the thread ["Define a control sequence after that a space matters"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338784/118714) which was started at TeX - LaTeX StackExchange in November 10, 2016 :

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{totcount}
% \usepackage{pgffor}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyMacroNamePrefix@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\name{%
  \long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\MyMacroNamePrefix@innername{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\MyMacroNamePrefix@innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\MyMacroNamePrefix@Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
\makeatother

\newtotcounter{questions}
\newcommand\newq[4]{%
    \name\name{@ifdefinable}{qa:\arabic{questions}.Number}{%
      \name\edef{qa:\arabic{questions}.Number}{\arabic{questions}}%
    }%
    \name\newcommand*{qa:\arabic{questions}.Date}{#1}%
    \name\newcommand*{qa:\arabic{questions}.Time}{#2}%
    \name\newcommand*{qa:\arabic{questions}.Question}{#3}%
    \name\newcommand*{qa:\arabic{questions}.Answer}{#4}%
    \stepcounter{questions}%
}%

\newq{268}%
{10:25}%
{Can you create a latex project with multiple documents?}%
{Yes, at least you can in Overleaf. You click on the menu in the top-left, and change main document to the tex file you want to compile.%
}

\begin{document}

\par\noindent
\name{qa:0.Number}\\
\name{qa:0.Date}\\
\name{qa:0.Time}\\
\name{qa:0.Question}\\
\name{qa:0.Answer}

\end{document}
```

[image]