# Fully expand macro argument

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I am sure this has been answered already, but I cannot seem to find any answer that explains it in core TeX primitives and that I understand on a token level, e.g. I definitely don't want to get into `expl3` before I got a grip on TeX itself.

What I am trying to do is basically just being able to write macros that can be used in a nested fashion using braces like `\amacro{\bmacro{bla}}`, first evaluating `\bmacro{bla}` to e.g. `la` (argument without first token = `\@cdr`) and then plugging that into `\amacro`, evaluating to `l` (only first token of argument = `\@car`).

```
\catcode`\@=11 %
\def\@car#1#2\@nil{#1}
\def\@cdr#1#2\@nil{#2}
\def\amacro#1{%
    \edef\tempa{#1}%
    \@car\tempa\@nil%
}
\def\bmacro#1{%
    \edef\tempa{#1}%
    \@cdr\tempa\@nil%
}
\catcode`\@=12 %

    a: \amacro{bla}\par
    b: \bmacro{bla}\par
    a(b): \amacro{\bmacro{bla}}

\bye
```

Using `\edef` I try to ensure that the argument is fully expanded before I go and operate on it, but while the individual macro calls work fine, compilation fails with the nested way with

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.16 a(b): \amacro{\bmacro{bla}}

?
```

It's not that unexpected, since it kind of is a nested `\edef` on the same name so I could very well see it breaking that way, but I didn't really get around what `\inaccessible` means in this context and why it arises.

And then, of course, the main point, there *must* be a proper way to do this in TeX core primitives, right? There has to be some way of fully expanding an argument before doing something with it.

Comment: Add `\tracingmacros=1` right after `\begin{document}`, recompile, and look at the transcript (`.log`) file: you’ll be illuminated.  Anyhow, this looks like an X-Y question: could you illustrate exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to design nestable macros such that, when supplied with another macro, it does not operate on a argument token list like `\bmacro { b l a }` or `\@cdr b l a \@nil` but the argument fully expanded to `l a` so whatever it does (here: just grab the first token, discard the rest) is applied to the *result* of the inner macro.

Comment: if your macros are all expandable you can fully expand them but most tex commands are not just defined via expansion and like your `\amacro` and `\bmacro` use non-expandable assignments (`\edef` here) so they have no "full expansion" as they are not expandable. the `\inaccessible` is added as you have `\edef bla{` (as you expanded `\tempa`) and `\edef` requires a control sequence to define so that is inserted as an error recovery

Comment: but `\edef` has a control sequence: `\tempa`, so it should just go away — and here is probably where my understanding is still wrong **EDIT:** wait...

Comment: no you pre-expanded it in a surrounding edef so you have, as I said, `\edef blah` .The answer to your final sentence is "No, there is no way to fully expand an argument, unless it is expandable".

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66168

Comment: Two months ago there was a discussion "Expand multiple math-tokens before detokenize." In my answer I tried to show a strategy for having control over the order in time in which expansion of things takes place. Although it didn't get many likes yet, it might be of interest to you:  [Expand multiple math-tokens before detokenize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434481/118714)

Comment: Be aware that `\edef` itself does not just trigger expansion but does also cause (La)TeX to perform an assignment. Performing an assignment is different from replacing tokens by other tokens. The latter happens at expansion-time (in TeX' mouth). The further does not happen at expansion-time (but in TeX' stomach). Thus an `\edef` or a `\def` or whatever assignment-command nested inside another `\edef` will not be carried out when expansion is triggered by that other ("surrounding") `\edef`, but will be considered an unexpandable control sequence token that is just to be left in place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you're missing `\expandafter`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\amacro#1{%
  \edef\tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\@car\tempa\@nil 
}
\def\bmacro#1{%
  \edef\tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\@cdr\tempa\@nil 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a: \amacro{bla}

b: \bmacro{bla}

%    a(b): \amacro{\bmacro{bla}}

\end{document}
```

otherwise `\@car` will just produce `\temp` and `\@cdr` nothing.

You cannot nest `\bmacro` in `\amacro`, because `\edef` is not expandable.

On the other hand, with LuaTeX there is `\expanded` (and it will be also in the other engines in a near future).

```
% compile with lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\amacro#1{%
  \expandafter\@car\expanded{#1}\@nil
}
\def\bmacro#1{%
  \expandafter\@cdr\expanded{#1}\@nil
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a: \amacro{bla}

b: \bmacro{bla}

a(b): \amacro{\bmacro{bla}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting to hear, though I won't mark this answer as *accepted* until `\expanded` is available in LaTeX, at least. Is it also planned for plain TeX?

Comment: @PeterNerlich `\expanded` is a _primitive_: it's available in plain LuaTeX today, and will be in the other engines for TL'19 (we are just waiting on a code change for XeTeX).

Comment: @PeterNerlich Your question uses LaTeX, so the link to plain is a bit odd.

Comment: Yeah, I know. While I use LaTeX, I often see a distinction between "only LaTeX" and "real/plain TeX" online when searching for ways to do what I want. From that my impression is mostly that LaTeX solutions are often single commands with longer names that do not really present any complex functionality and the real stuff is happening in plain TeX anyway. So I rather ask for plain TeX solutions right away instead of getting suggestions like "using Expl/WhateverTeX..." etc. which may lead to a specific solution but don't help me to understand and learn how to construct what I want.

Comment: But I don't want to start reading a long TeX book from scratch either, neither do I want to start with the most primitive examples, I want to get to the more interesting problems that I come across right away. I know, this is an educational dilemma...

Comment: @PeterNerlich Then you should at least read some introduction about the difference between the engines (with their primitives) and the formats. Maybe this will help you to clarify your question next time.

Comment: @JosephWright So `\expanded` will finally come to pdfTeX too? That means that in the future `\str_if_eq_x:nn` would be `\str_if_eq:xx` and all `:xx` arguments will be expandable? And probably `:f` disappear?

Comment: @Manuel It is in development pdfTeX for TL'19, so we will get it. The expansion `\expanded` does isn't quite `x`-type, hence the new `e`-type in `expl3`: try a `#` token!.  We also don't want to change the expandability of existing `x`-type functions. The next `expl3` release will rename a few functions as a result, including `\str_if_eq_x:nn` to `\str_if_eq_e:nn` (`\str_case_x:nn` is a more 'interesting' one). We won't entirely drop `f`-type expansion: it can be used to do 'look ahead' without grabbing arguments (as TeX does at the start of a table cell, for example) ...

Comment: ... and has different behaviour on 'hitting' a non-expandable token. However, we do expect over time to move to using more `e`-type and less `f`-type code, but only once `\expanded` is well-established (several years). (We are still waiting on feedback from the XeTeX maintainers.)

Comment: Just found back to this question. I don't fully understand the context anymore and this will be a task for another time for me, but I confirmed it is available now so yay! Accepted answer, here you go!

Answer (score 6):

Basically, I’m posting this answer because it is way too long for a comment.

As usual, [@egreg’s post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443983/69818)
already answers your question in essence.  However, I think that you are having
difficulties in understanding exactly what expansion means,
and that you tend to confuse expansion with digestion
(*i.e.*, execution in the stomach), two concepts that are quite different from each other.  This is absolutely excusable, since TeX’s behavior in this regard is really hard to understand, and [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66168/69818) that David Carlisle has linked to is very helpful in explaining this subtle topic; nevertheless, I think that it could also be helpful to show you exactly what happens when your code is executed, in a step-by-step fashion.  This is precisely what this answer does.

---

## What happens with `\amacro{bla}`

The tokens

```
\amacro{bla}
```

are replaced with

```
\edef\tempa{bla} \@car\tempa\@nil
```

Then TeX processes `\edef`: this is an unexpandable token, so it is forwarded
to the “stomach”, where it is executed.  Since the tokens in the replacement
text are all unexpandable (they are just character tokens), this means that
`\tempa` is defined to expand into `bla`.  Next, TeX finds `\@car`,
which is defined as

```
\def\@car#1#2\@nil{#1}
```

In particular, being a macro, `\@car` is expandable.
The first argument of `\@car` is undelimited, the second is delimited by `\@nil`;
in our case,
`\tempa` (!) is taken as the first argument, and the second argument is empty.
Note that `\@nil` is gobbled as well as part of the expansion process.
The result of the expansion is the first argument, that is, `\tempa`.
In conclusion,

```
\@car\tempa\@nil
```

is replaced with

```
\tempa
```

This is again an expandable token, so it is expanded:
the current definition of `\tempa` is `bla`, so

```
bla
```

is what remains in the token stream after the expansion.
These are all unexpandable tokens, so they are sent to the stomach,
where they are executed.  The final result is that TeX typesets “abc”
(note that it was already in horizontal mode) and that a temporary
definition has been made.

---

## What happens with `\bmacro{bla}`

This is very similar to the previous case, hence I‘ll leave it
“as an exercise” to you.  The final result is that

```
\bmacro{bla}
```

is replaced by nothing, *i.e.*, it is removed from the token stream,
but always with the side effect of defining `\tempa` to expanda into `bla`.

---

## What happens with `\amacro{\bmacro{bla}}`

This is, of course, the most interesting case.
Initially, the token stream contains

```
\amacro{\bmacro{bla}}
```

According to the definition of `\amacro`, this is replaced with

```
\edef\tempa{\bmacro{bla}} \@car\tempa\@nil
```

Again, the next thing that TeX processes is `\edef`, which, I repeat, is not expandable and proceeds therefore to the stomach, where it is *executed* (not expanded!): `\tempa` is defined as a macro that will expand to the *current full* expansion of `\bmacro{bla}`.  So TeX begins to *fully* expand `\bmacro{bla}`; according to the current definition of `\bmacro`, the first expansion step yields `\edef\tempa{bla} \@cdr\tempa\@nil`, and TeX looks at each of these ten tokens, in turn, to see if it happens to be expandable.  Now:

- `\edef` is unexpandable, so it is left alone;
- `\tempa`, on the other hand, *is* expandable, so (aha!) it is expanded
  according to its current definition, which, at this moment, is still
  the definition set, as a side effect, by the execution of the line

  ```
  b: \bmacro{bla}\\
  ```

  found in your source file, that is, `bla`; these three tokens are
  unexpandable and therefore they remain as they are;
- a `{` token follows, which is unexpandable, and hence is left alone;
- similarly, the next four tokens, `b`, `l`, `a`, and `}` are
  copied ”verbatim” into the replacement text;
- `\@cdr` is expandable, so it is expanded: `\tempa` becomes its first
  argument, while the second argument of `\@cdr` is empty; `\@nil` is
  also gobbled as the argument delimiter; according to its definition,
  `\@cdr` is expanded into its second argument, that is, into nothing;
- at this point, the replacement text of the definition that we were
  executing (recall that it was

  ```
  \edef\tempa{\bmacro{bla}}
  ```

  see above where we said “it is *executed* (not expanded!)”) has been
  expanded fully, yielding `\edef bla{bla}`.

In conclusion, `\tempa` is defined as a macro whose replacement text is

```
\edef bla{bla}
```

(nine tokens).  This completes the *execution* (not expansion) of the code

```
\edef\tempa{\bmacro{bla}}
```

What remains now in the token stream is

```
\@car\tempa\@nil
```

`\@car` is expandable, so it is expanded (obviously…): its first argument
is `\tempa` and its second argument is empty;
the expansion is the first argument, that is, `\tempa`.
All in all, what remains in the token stream is

```
\tempa
```

(of course, `\@nil` has been gobbled when the arguments of `\@car`
where fetched).  This again is an expandable token, whose current expansion is

```
\edef bla{bla}
```

because of the definition we have just performed.  So TeX processes `\edef`,
which is unexpandable and is hence *executed* in the stomach… and, well,
I think that now the reason of the error is perfectly clear.

(Deep breath.)

Comment: Thank you! So far, so clear. Then I add the `\expandafter`, or rather, since I need to get rid of `\edef` anyways, delete that and `\tempa` and instead replace it with... the fully expanded character stream, but how?