# Adding a comand hook to \appendix with cleveref

Tags: hooks, lthooks

I'm trying to set a hook to the `\appendix` command using the new hook management system.  However, when `cleveref` is loaded, the hook fails with error "Illegal parameter number in definition of \appendix." at `begindocument`, hence presumably when the hook is being set by `ltcmdhooks`.  The message happens regularly 46 times, same number in different documents, I think it is the number of `##` in the definition done by `cleveref`.

The use of equivalent `etoolbox` code does not result in the same issue.

The MWE below is not really the "real use case", but is enough to reproduce the problem:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{\label{appendix}}

% 'etoolbox' works though
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \preto{\appendix}{\label{appendix}}{}{}

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\appendix

\end{document}
```

I'm a little at a loss at what to do with this. But understanding better what the culprit is and particularly why `ltcmdhooks` fails where `etoolbox` does not, so that I get a better grasp on what I can do with the former, would be much welcome.

**Edit**: I'd like to add one dimension to the problem here, if that's OK.  My actual use case is that I'm trying to do some setup when the `\appendix` starts, in a package meant for publication.  Now, I cannot hope to be sure of what `\appendix` may contain, since it is redefined in so many places in one or another package or class.  I was expecting to keep the hook, but that, if things went sour in one or another use case, I'd be able to instruct users to manually remove the hook and restablish things to working condition. But adding and removing the hook still breaks `\appendix`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}[package-1]{\label{appendix}}
\RemoveFromHook{cmd/appendix/before}[package-1]

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Would there be a safe way to disable the hook before it gets applied at `begindocument`?

Comment: That's a known issue (with no known solution so far :).  The patching mechanism tries to be clever and avoid `\scantokens` as much as possible, and in case of very simple macros (for example, ones that don't take arguments), it patches by treating the macro more or less as a token list.  However this procedure currently fails when there's a single parameter token (`##`) in the definition.

Comment: Hi @PhelypeOleinik! Thanks! And why does `etoolbox` works for this case? I'm very "curious" here since I'm relying in one such hook to `\appendix`, and I have no hope of being able to know what "arbitrary packages or classes" may put there. That being the case, should I refrain from using `ltcmdhooks`?

Comment: `etoolbox` works because it uses the `\scantokens` approach (which is also not fool-proof, but works well in this case).  You should definitely _not_ prefer manual patching over the method built into the kernel (well, maybe for now, while it's broken, but I hope to have it fixed for the November release).  It's getting late, so if you can hold your curiosity until tomorrow, I can write a detailed explanation on why and how this is happening

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Absolutely, there is no hurry. I just posted it today, despite being late, because I was around this for quite some time and was about to "close the shop" for today as well.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Btw `\tl_put_left:Nn` also works, but anything but `\AddToHook` seems inappropriate here...

Comment: Regarding your edit:  there's no use in doing `\RemoveFromHook`.  Once you add some code to a generic `cmd` hook, that command enters the patching queue and nothing takes it out of there.  What prevents the patch from happening is declaring the hook with `\NewHook` or `\ActivateGenericHook` (`\ProvideHook` in the current release).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I did not understand how `\NewHook`, `\ActivateGenericHook` or `\ProvideHook` could prevent the patch from happening if `\RemoveFromHook` does not do it. You mean here that I could create a hook with a different name and then use `\DisableHook` altogether?

Comment: Or is it the example you gave in your answer: `\ActivateGenericHook` *before* the package is loaded?

Comment: Because `\RemoveFromHook` works exclusively on the hook's code pool, while `\ActivateGenericHook` tells `ltcmdhooks` if the patching should happen.  The only restriction on the position of `\ActivateGenericHook` is that it has to appear before patching happens (that is, before `\begin{document}` in this case).

Comment: The issue is fixed in the development branch, and will be available in the next release (https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/699).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik :) Thank you very, very much!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I took a look at the commits, and wow! I've still a lot to learn! :-)

Comment: The code in there probably looks more complicated than it actually is, so it can cope with several different cases.  I added another chunk to my (already rather long) answer with the basic idea implemented

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks again! I do get the general concept from the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are roughly two ways to patch a command:  via `\scantokens`, and via expansion+redefinition.  There's a (not so) brief explanation of both at the end of this answer.  When `ltcmdhooks` can detect the type of command, so that it knows exactly the `<parameter text>` of the command, it patches by expansion+redefinition, so it has no restriction on the catcode settings in force when the macro was defined.  In the case of `\appendix`, it takes no arguments, so it can be treated as a token list and expanded, then redefined with the added material.

For example, here's a simple sketch of how it works:

```
\def\appendix{%
  \typeout{This starts the appendix.}}

\def\append#1{%
  \expandafter\appendaux\expandafter{#1}#1}
\def\appendaux#1#2#3{%
  \def#2{#1#3}}

\append\appendix{\typeout{I added this.}}

\appendix
```

However, what I did not anticipate when I wrote that code, is the case when the original definition of `\appendix` contains `##` (try this definition in the code above):

```
\def\appendix{%
  \typeout{This starts the appendix. ##BOOM!}}
```

When `\appendix` is defined like that, TeX's definition scanner sees `#6#6`, and replaces that by a single parameter token `#6` in the definition of `\appendix`, so far so good.  However when you expand the command, TeX also returns a single `#6`, and then when you try to redefine the command you have:

```
\def\appendix{%
  \typeout{This starts the appendix. #BOOM!}%
  \typeout{I added this.}}
```

which contains an illegal parameter (`#B`), and the definition errors.

I have [changed `ltcmdhooks`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/699) to handle this case (there's a brief explanation below), but meanwhile you can use `\ActivateGenericHook` (or `\ProvideHook` in LaTeX 2021-06-01) to tell `ltcmdhooks` that you have already patched the command, so it won't try patching, then you do the patching manually using `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\IfFormatAtLeastTF{2021-11-15}%
  {\ActivateGenericHook}% LaTeX > 2021-11-15
  {\ProvideHook}%         LaTeX = 2021-06-01
    {cmd/appendix/before}
\pretocmd\appendix
  {\UseHook{cmd/appendix/before}}
  {}{\FAILED}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{\label{appendix}}

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\appendix

\end{document}
```

##### Why the above works

The interface for `ltcmdhooks` in `\AddToHook` is supposed to work as follows:

If an end user writes `\AddToHook{cmd/name/before}{code}`, and the hook `cmd/name/before` doesn't exist yet (which implies that the command `\name` doesn't have that hook "installed"), then the code tries to patch that hook in the command.

If the end user writes `\AddToHook{cmd/name/before}{code}`, and the hook `cmd/name/before` already exists, this (probably) means that the command `\name` already has that hook, so it just adds the code to the hook, and leaves the command be.

This means that a package author may want to fine-tune the position of the `cmd/name/before` hook (for example, `\def\name{<some initialization>\UseHook{cmd/name/before}<definition>}`), then we don't want `ltcmdhooks` patching the command again (it would be wrong to add the same hook twice), so we tell `ltcmdhooks` that the hook already exists by saying `\ActivateGenericHook{cmd/name/before}`, then patching is no longer attempted.

This works for your case because you then manually add the hook to the command, and then tell `ltcmdhooks` that pathching is no longer needed.  See section [**3 Package Author Interface**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex-dev/base/ltcmdhooks-doc.pdf#section.0.3) of the `ltcmdhooks` documentation.

So in essence, you, as the package author, are appropriating the `\appendix` command, by adding the hook yourself (exactly where `ltcmdhooks` would add it), and then telling `ltcmdhooks` to not patch it by using `\ActivateGenericHook`.

If instead of `\appendix` you were adding hooks to `\UniqueCommandFromMyPackage`, then you could use `\NewHook` instead of `\ActivateGenericHook` (the effect would be identical), because there would be no possibility of a name conflict.

##### How LaTeX2ε handles this case now

**The problem:** Turns out in the described case we're in a dead-end.  When you write a definition like

```tex
\def\foo#1{#1##X}
```

TeX stores its `<replacement text>` as a token list containing:

```pascal
out_param 1, par_token #, letter X
```

(`out_param 1` is `#1` to be replaced by the actual parameter when the macro is expanded, `par_token #` is a catcode 6 `#`, and `letter X` is a catcode 11 `X`).

Then, when you expand `\foo` with `#1` (`par_token #, character 1`), TeX replaces `out_param 1` and you have:

```pascal
par_token #, character 1, par_token #, letter X
```

which is equivalent to typing `#1#X`.  If you plug that back into a new definition of `\foo` you'll have:

```tex
\def\foo#1{#1#X}
```

which is obviously wrong (and thus the `Illegal parameter number` error).  And at this point you have no way to tell what was an actual parameter when the macro was defined, and what was a single parameter token.

**Half solution:**  There is one very simple case that can be easily detected  and solved (which coincidentally is the one in your question):  a macro without parameters.  In this case, the macro has no argument, so any loose `##` in its definition cannot possibly be confused with a parameter, so we can treat this such macros as token lists (in the `expl3` sense) and do something akin to `\tl_put_right:Nn` and problem solved.

Another relatively simpler case is when the macro has no `##` in its definition.  In this case we don't have to worry about confusing parameters, so we treat the macro normally (this was the case implemented initially).  LaTeX uses a rather simple loop to check if a macro has a parameter token in its definition (`\__hook_if_has_hash:nTF`):  it looks at every token in the defintion, and compares it with `#`.

**The other half:**  When the macro falls into the general case of having both parameters *and* parameter tokens in its definition (like `\foo` above), then we have to manually re-double every parameter token in the definition, so that it can be re-made.  To do that, instead of expanding `\foo` with `#1`, LaTeX expands it with `\c_@@_hash_tl`, so `\foo{\c_@@_hash_tl}` becomes a definition like:

```
\foo#1{\c_@@_hash_tl 1#X}
```

then we loop through the replacement text of the macro (inside the braces) and double every `##`, and replace every `\c_@@_hash_tl` by a single `#`, which then gives:

```
\foo#1{#1##X}
```

and then we can do the definition normally (*phew*!)

---

##### Patching with `\scantokens`

([wordier description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498229/134574))

Suppose a macro defined with

```
\long\def\mycmd[#1]#2{\typeout{#1//#2}}
```

To append some code to it via `\scantokens`, you first do `\meaning\mycmd` to get a string like:

```
\long macro:[#1]#2->\typeout {#1//#2}
```

(with usual `\detokenize` catcodes: all 12 except spaces, which are catcode 10), then you use a delimited macro to separate the `<prefixes>`, the `<parameter text>`, and the `<replacement text>`, roughly like this:

```
\def\split#1{\expandafter\splitaux\meaning#1\relax}
\expanded{%
  \noexpand\def\noexpand\splitaux#1\detokenize{macro:}#2->#3\relax}{%
    \def\prefixes{#1}%
    \def\parameter{#2}%
    \def\replacement{#3}}
```

(I'm using `\def\prefixes{#1}`, etc. for the sake of understandability, but in reality you would inject everything expandably instead;  see the definition of `\__kernel_prefix_arg_replacement:wN` in `expl3-code.tex`, and `\etb@patchcmd` in `etoolbox.sty` if you're feeling brave).

At this point you have every part of the definition as a string separately.  Now you can either append or prepend some code to `\replacement` (or replace some part of it, as it's done in `\patchcmd`), or in rarer cases change `\prefixes` or `\parameter`.  At this point you have three strings, each of which is a part of the definition.  To reconstruct the definition you need:

```
<prefixes>\def\mycmd<parameter text>{<replacement text>}
```

but the three parts you have are still catcode 12 tokens, which are no good.  Here comes the `\scantokens` part:  you rescan those strings back to "normal" tokens:

```
\expanded{%
  \noexpand\scantokens{%
  % <prefixes>\def         \mycmd<parameter text>{<replacement text>}
    \prefixes \def\noexpand\mycmd\parameter      {\replacement      <added material>}%
  }%
}
```

which, after `\expanded` does its job, becomes:

```
\scantokens{%
  \long\def\mycmd[#1]#2{\typeout {#1//#2}<added material>}%
}%
```

then `\scantokens` does its thing and turns everything into tokens using the current catcode settings, and then the definition is carried out normally.

The advantage of this method is that you can do virtually any manipulation in any part of the definition.

The disatvantages are a few:

- You need to know what catcodes were in force when the definition was first made (when patching you usually need to verify that a simple round of `\meaning`–`\scantokens` doesn't change the meaning of the macro) otherwise you can't patch safely;
- If the macro was created with some combination of `\edef` and `\detokenize` to forcibly make some catcode 12 tokens, you will probably not be able to patch that macro (for example, `\splitaux` as defined above in this answer cannot ever be patched with `\patchcmd` because it contains letters (for example `m`) of both catcodes 11 and 12);
- If the `<parameter text>` of the macro contains the characters `->`, you won't be able to patch the macro.

##### Patching with expansion+redefinition

This method is much simpler, but requires previous knowledge of how the macro was defined.  This can be done in few cases, namely when you know exactly what the `<parameter text>` of the macro is.  The cases known by the kernel are when the macro was defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, or with `ltcmd` (`\NewDocumentCommand` or `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`), or with `\newcommand` with an optional argument, or when the macro takes no argument.

Suppose the same macro from before, but defined with:

```
\newcommand\mycmd[2][default]{\typeout{#1//#2}}
```

(it will have an internal macro called `\\mycmd`, but for the sake of simplicity let's call it `\mycmd` as well), then we know for sure its `<parameter text>` is `[#1]#2`.  Knowing what arguments the macro expects, we can feed it `#1`, `#2`, ... as arguments, so for `\mycmd` we would do:

```
\mycmd[#1]{#2}
```

which would then expand to the `<replacement text>` of the macro, with the first parameter (`#1`) replaced by `#6112` (the parameter token `#` followed by the character `1`).  The patching scheme would be something like:

```
\expanded{%
  \def\noexpand\mycmd[#1]#2{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\mycmd[#1]{#2}<added material>}%
  }%
}
```

then after the `\expanded` is done you are left with:

```
\def\mycmd[#1]#2{\typeout{#1//#2}<added material>}}
```

which is exactly what you had with the `\scantokens` approach, except that you didn't turn tokens into a string, so catcodes don't matter at all here.

The advantages of this method are roughly the disadvantages of the `\scantokens` method:

- catcodes don't matter at all;
- you can patch complicated macros (including the `\splitaux` macro from before) using this method given you know exactly what its `<parameter text>` is;
- the `<parameter text>` of the macro may contain any token your heart desires (as long as you know what token it is); and
- this method doesn't need a sanity check to ensure that the macro can be patched correctly.

The disadvantage is the requirement for the method to work:  you need to know exactly what the `<parameter text>` is.

Comment: Hi Phelype! Thank you very much for the thorough explanation. I think I got the general idea of what the task of the hook infrastructure is, though probably a number of details are beyond my league.

Comment: Regarding the suggested use of `etoolbox` to `\UseHook{cmd/appendix/before}` as a patch. Let me see if I understand well the intention here: to get things working promptly while still adhering to the more "civil" machinery of the new hook management system. Is that the intention there?

Comment: However, since the package in question is not yet released, maybe the "best fix" for me is just waiting to see what you come up with. ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs When `\AddToHook{cmd/name/...}{}` is used, two things happen: some code is added to the `cmd/name/...` hook, and independently from that, `ltcmdhooks` checks if it has to patch `\name` to add the hook to it.  It will only patch `\name` if the hook didn't exist previously.  I added a **Why the above works** section to the answer that hopefully makes things clearer.  Feel free to ask.  And no, this is part of the documented interface, so you could use this solution permanently (though it would require `etoolbox`; if you don't want the requirement, then wait until the November release).

Comment: Phelype, I think I got the relation of the parts better now. Thanks once again! Indeed, I was not requiring `etoolbox` at all, and it seems too much just for that. I might well wait, which isn't a problem. To start with because I'll need at least another couple of weeks to wrap things up, what's a couple more?  ;-)

Comment: Phelype, I had one other little idea, tell me what you think of it. Suppose "before begin document" I get `\meaning\appendix` and do a string search (`\str_if_in:NnTF`) in it, if I find `##`, I issue a `\ActivateGenericHook` and make the hook no-op, otherwise I let it do its job as usual. This would grant a decent result even without `etoolbox`. Do you think this would be a good idea? Is the `##` the only known case of trouble there? (I'm just thinking "out loud" here, I'll probably just wait for the release anyway).

Comment: @gusbrs I wouldn't bother.  Yes, `##` (two or more) are what cause the trouble here, but this solution (if I understood your intent) would make the code not work in the current release, while it can work using the intended interface.  If you just want to avoid `etoolbox`, you can replace the `\pretocmd` line by `\tl_gput_left:Nn \appendix { ... }` (in the specific case of a command that takes no arguments).

Comment: Well, it wouldn't work when it couldn't work, meaning if someone had redefined it in a way which would make `\AddToHook` choke, otherwise I think it would. But, you are right, it'd still be just too ad hoc to be worth it. Anyway, I was really just curious.  Indeed, if there's one package which is likely not to be used with the one I'm making, it is cleveref, it just happened to be the offending case I found, what I really wanted to know were "the bounds of safe hooking". And your answer was great for a better grasp.  Thanks again!

Comment: @gusbrs Oh, so I misunderstood your idea.  Yeah, if you want to stick to `\AddToHook` only, then all there's to do is wait, unfortunately.  About “the bounds of safe hooking”, there should be little restriction on that: see section 2 (Restrictions and Operational details) of the `ltcmdhooks` documentation.  Basically, hooking into a command is not possible when the command can't be patched (section 2.1 Patching), or when adding the hook disrupts the normal working of the command (2.2 Commands that look ahead).  [cont'd]

Comment: Regarding patching, `ltcmdhooks` should be even more permissive than `\patchcmd` (modulo bugs :), and if it's not possible to patch you should get an error message right away, but this should be rare.  Regarding disrupting the command: this depends on what the command does, and cannot be checked programatically, so here you have to be much more careful about what commands you add hooks to (for example `\AddToHook{cmd/section/after}{code}` is recipe for disaster).

Comment: Well, I have read the documentation, I was concerned because the case did not fit in any of the documented restrictions, and I did not understand well what is going on. Now I get it. My expectation was indeed that `ltcmdhooks` would be "as safe as it gets", specialy the `before` ones. But, one thing that I do miss from `etoolbox` patches are the ability to use the original command's arguments. But, unless `\UseHook` were able to pass them around, which it can't, that's understandable.