# Define a macro in terms of other macro names

Tags: macros

Please see the define mechanism below, where I am defining a macro in terms of two other macro definitions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\a{A}
\def\b{B}
\def\c{CC}


\def\expandafter\csname\a\b\endcsname{\c}

\AB

\end{document}
```

The way I have defined it, I thought that `\a` and `\b` are building
`AB`. So, `\AB` should expand to `CC`.

But when executed, I get the message,

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.12 \AB
>
> ?
> ```

The file compiles fine without the `\AB` call. So, some defining mechanism is happening.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: If you are getting confused with the appropriate location of `\expandafter`, consider `\makeatletter \@namedef{\a\b}{\c} \makeatother`, which defines `\AB`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With your present code

```
\def\expandafter\csname\a\b\endcsname{\c}
```

you are overwriting the `TeX`  primitive `\expandafter` such that it *must* be followed by `\csname\a\b\endcsname`. Then the construct

```
\expandafter\csname\a\b\endcsname
```

will expand to `\c`. With an empty document nothing happens, but try to type something and you'll get a puzzling

```
! Use of \expandafter doesn't match its definition.
```

What you *do* want is to hold `\def` for a while, so you must put the `\expandafter`*before* it. The code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\a{A}
\def\b{B}
\def\c{CC}
\expandafter\def\csname\a\b\endcsname{\c}
\AB
\end{document}
```

will do what you expect.

My favourite reading about `\expandafter`: [A Tutorial on `\expandafter`](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf) (TUGboat 9)

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning the `\expandafter` tutorial.  A necessity for mucking about with cross-referencing macros.

Answer (score 2):

The control sequences `\a`, `\b` and `\c` are already defined in the LaTeX 2ε-kernel.

`\MYa`, `\MYb` and `\MYc` will be used instead.

For the sake of having fun playing around with (La)TeX's expansion-mechanisms, I offer the following approaches:

With this approach `\csname`'s triggering of expansion until finding a matching`\endcsname` is used in combination with `\expandafter` for tricking LaTeX into expanding things behind the `\csname..\endcsname`-construct as well:

```
% Use LaTeX for compiling this:

\newcommand*\MYa{A}
\newcommand*\MYb{B}
\newcommand*\MYc{CC}

\expandafter\newcommand\csname\MYa\MYb\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\MYc}

\show\AB

\stop
```

You can also combine `\expandafter` with `\exchange`:

```
% Use LaTeX for compiling this:

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

\newcommand*\MYa{A}
\newcommand*\MYb{B}
\newcommand*\MYc{CC}

\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\MYc}}{\expandafter\newcommand\csname\MYa\MYb\endcsname}%

\show\AB

\stop
```

In many situations a variant of `\exchange` is useful which adds curly braces:

```
% Use LaTeX for compiling this:

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}

\newcommand*\MYa{A}
\newcommand*\MYb{B}
\newcommand*\MYc{CC}

\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\MYc}{\expandafter\newcommand\csname\MYa\MYb\endcsname}%

\show\AB

\stop
```

There is also the macro `\name` which takes everything before the first pair of curly braces for one argument and everything within the first pair of curly braces for another argument and which returns things after having applied `\csname..\endcsname` to the things within curly braces:

`\name\newcommand{macro}...` → `\newcommand\macro...`
   `\name\global\long\def{macro}...` → `\global\long\def\macro...`
   `\name\string{macro}` → `\string\macro`
   `\name{macro}` → `\macro`
   `\name\name\let{macroA}={macroB}` → `\name\let\macroA={macroB}` → `\let\macroA=\macroB`

```
% Use LaTeX for compiling this:

\newcommand*\MYa{A}
\newcommand*\MYb{B}
\newcommand*\MYc{CC}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%    
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\name{%
  \long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%

\name\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\MYa\MYb}\expandafter{\MYc}%
% ->
% \romannumeral0\innername{\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter}{\MYa\MYb}\expandafter{\MYc}
% ->
% %\romannumeral0-expansion in progress
% \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname\MYa\MYb\endcsname}{ \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter}\expandafter{\MYc}%
% -> ( \expandafter-chain "hits" \csname )
% %\romannumeral0-expansion in progress
% \exchange{\AB}{ \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter}\expandafter{\MYc}%
% ->
% %\romannumeral0-expansion in progress
% <space>\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter\AB\expandafter{\MYc}%
% ->
% %\romannumeral0-expansion terminated:
% \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter\AB\expandafter{\MYc}%
% -> ( \expandafter-chain "hits" \MYc )
% \newcommand\AB{CC}%

\show\AB

\stop
```

In case `\PassFirstToSecond` is available:

```
% Use LaTeX for compiling this:

\newcommand*\MYa{A}
\newcommand*\MYb{B}
\newcommand*\MYc{CC}

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%    
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%    
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\name{%
  \long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%

\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\MYc}{\name\newcommand*{\MYa\MYb}}%

\show\AB

\stop
```

My favourite reading about `\expandafter` (and about how to keep the amount of `\expandafter` short) is the thread ["How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320933/118714).  ;-)