# Can't define a macro with a name derived from another macro's value: `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`

Tags: expansion, package-options, csname, mfirstuc

### What happened

Given that the macro `\CurrentOption` whose value is an unknown string of English letters already exists in the document, I want to create another macro whose name is the capitalized value of `\CurrentOption`.

For example, if `\CurrentOption` contains the string `word`, I would like to define a macro called `Word`.

However, the error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.8     \expandafter\def\csname\temp
                                     YesOrNo\endcsname{1}
```

is produced when compiling the following MWE with `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc} % For \xmakefirstuc, to capitalize the first letter.

\begin{document}
    \def\CurrentOption{word}
    \edef\temp{\xmakefirstuc{\CurrentOption}}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\temp\endcsname{1} % <--- The error is here
\end{document}
```

How should I change the code above, without removing the statement `\def\CurrentOption{word}`, so that a macro named `Word` with the value `1` is defined?

---

### General purpose of code

I am writing a package in which case-insensitive options should be processed. For example, if the package receives the option `word`, I would like the package to `xdef` the macro whose name is `Word`. Similaly, if the package receives the option `wOrD`, I would like the package to `xdef` the same macro `Word`.

My plan is to achieve this using the following code within the package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{courseMacros}[6/13/2022 v2.0, Miriam Briskman]

\RequirePackage{mfirstuc}

\DeclareOption*{
    \edef\temp{\xmakefirstuc{\CurrentOption}}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\temp\endcsname{1}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

% .... the rest of the package ...
```

Note that `\CurrentOption` above is [a defined macro expanding to the current option's value](https://latexref.xyz/Class-and-package-commands.html#index-_005cCurrentOption).

Nonetheless, the same `! Missing \endcsname inserted.` error is generated when using the package above in a `TeX` file.

---

### Console Output

The full output of the console when compiling the 1st MWE is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(example.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(C:\Users\Miriam Briskman\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\arti
cle.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

(C:\Users\Miriam Briskman\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size
10.clo))
(C:\Users\Miriam Briskman\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mfirstuc\
mfirstuc.sty
(C:\Users\Miriam Briskman\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\
etoolbox.sty))
(C:\Users\Miriam Briskman\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend
\l3backend-pdftex.def) (C:\temp\example.aux)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.8     \expandafter\xdef\csname\temp
                                     \endcsname{1}
?
```

---

### Research so far

1. **Joseph Wright** in their answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519/256551 provides an impressive explanation of how expansion works in `TeX`. However, non of the examples uses a macro within `\csname ... \endcsname`.
2. **campa** in their answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515203/256551 successfully demonstrates how to use soem macros `\a` and `\b` within another macro's name, but `\a` and `\b` are defined as simple strings, `\def\a{A}` and `\def\b{B}`, while the `\temp` macro in my MWE is itself calling a macro.
3. When I change my MWE to either of

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}
    \def\CurrentOption{word}
    \edef\temp{\CurrentOption} % <--- \xmakefirstuc{\CurrentOption} changed to \CurrentOption
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\temp\endcsname{1}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}
    \def\CurrentOption{word}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\CurrentOption\endcsname{1}
\end{document}
```

the code executes without errors. These changes, however, prevent the macro's name from being capitalized using the macro `\xmakefirstuc`.

---

### Software Specifications

Executing `pdflatex --version` in my Windows 10's CMD outputs

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.10 (MiKTeX 22.3)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2021 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019
compiled with curl version 7.72.0; using libcurl/7.72.0 Schannel
compiled with expat version 2.2.10; using expat_2.2.10
compiled with jpeg version 9.4
compiled with liblzma version 50020052; using 50020052
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 3.1.4; using LibreSSL 3.1.4
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.4; using 4.4
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.12; using 4.12
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.7; using 4.7
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.4
compiled with xpdf version 4.02
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

---

How should the code in the 1st MWE be corrected to eliminate the error, without removing the definition of `\CurrentOption`, and still being able to capitalize the newly created macro?

Comment: you can not use \mkfirstuc for this, it is not expandable. You can use `\text_titlecase:n` from expl3. But you shouldn't define unconditionally commands like this, if you overwrite an important existing command you can break a lot.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you very much! How should the syntax `\text_titlecase:n` be used in the context of the MWE? Could you, please, write this solution as an answer to the question? I appreciate it very much!

Comment: If you really want to learn the internal working/understand what is going on, consider reading the TeXbook/TeX by topic.

Comment: @user202729, thank you very much for the great suggestion! I will definitely consult these resources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \def\CurrentOption{word}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn\text_titlecase:n{V}
    \cs_new:cpn {\text_titlecase:V\CurrentOption}{1}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \Word
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your task without any `\ExplSyntaxOn`, only by TeX primitives:

```
\def\defoptionmacro#1#2\relax#3{%
   \uppercase{\expandafter\xdef\csname #1}#2\endcsname{#3}%
}

% usage:
\def\CurrentOption{worD}
\lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\defoptionmacro\CurrentOption}\relax{1}

% test:
\meaning\Word  % it is macro:->1
```

First, `\lowercase` is processed and `\defoptionmacro word\relax{1}` is invoked. Second, the `\uppercase` is applied to the first token and then the `\csname...\endcsname` is completed.

But IMHO your requirement to do uppercase of the first character is due to you want to avoid to re-define existing macro or another control sequence. This can be done by different way: use a character typically not present in the control sequences. For example:

```
\def\defoptionmacro#1\relax#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname option?#1\endcsname{#2}}
```

Then the macro `\option?word` is defined. Of course, you must to use option-defined macros by the same prefix `option?` using `\csname...\endcsname`.

Comment: +1 for the great, working method and for the recommendation to use a special character. I will definitely consider that!