# expansion of a macro defined with \csname

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a problem with expanding and not expanding macros together with `\csname`. Please look at the following code:

```
% Save content of a macro via \csname
\def\LetCsVar#1#2{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname=#2}% #1=name, #2=definition
% Get the previous saved content of a macro via \csname
\def\GetCsVar#1{\csname#1\endcsname}% #1=name

\def\txt{Hallo\thinspace you}
txt: \meaning\txt\break  % prints: txt: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you

\count1=1
\LetCsVar{test\the\count1}{\txt}

% \txt can change here
\def\txt{Holla}

\def\a{\GetCsVar{test\the\count1}}
a: \meaning\a\break      % prints: a: macro:->\GetCsVar {test\the \count 1}

\edef\b{\GetCsVar{test\the\count1}}
b: \meaning\b\break      % prints: b: macro:->Hallo\kern .16667em you

\toks0=\expandafter{\a}
\edef\c{\the\toks0}
c: \meaning\c\break      % prints: c: macro:->\GetCsVar {test\the \count 1}
```

I wonder what to do to get a new macro after `\GetCsVar` with the meaning `macro:->Hallo\thinspace you` like the `\txt`-macro.

The problem is to expand `\GetCsVar` and `\the \count 1` and `\csname` but not the initial `\thinspace`.

Thank you, Peter

**Edit:**

Inspired by David Carlisles answer i created a new macro `\GetCsVarEx`:

```
\def\GetCsVarExp#1#2%
{%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
\def%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
\ax%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
{\csname#1\endcsname}%
\expandafter\let\csname#2\endcsname=\ax
}
```

Then i call

```
\GetCsVarExp{test\the\count1}{d}
```

and so `d: \meaning\d` prints my desired `d: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you`.

It works, but i would appreciate an even simpler way to fill the macro `\d`. Perhaps there is no?

Comment: it doesn't really help to edit in answers to the question after answers are posted, it makes the question and answer format of the site hard to follow for later readers.

Comment: you are using plain tex you could still use expl3, for layex users where expl3 is built-in, all this csname and expandafter control is handled with pre-defined functions. so you never have to do this by hand.

Comment: why `\def \ax` and then do `\let` rather than simply defining \csname#2\endcsname directly?

Comment: because i couldn't find out how to set all the expandafters than.

Comment: Don't edit in answers to questions. However, there is nothing wrong with questioners writing separate answers to their own questions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You want to expand three times, so need seven`\expandafter`

```
% Save content of a macro via \csname
\def\LetCsVar#1#2{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname=#2}% #1=name, #2=definition
% Get the previous saved content of a macro via \csname
\def\GetCsVar#1{\csname#1\endcsname}% #1=name

\def\txt{Hallo\thinspace you}
txt: {\tt\meaning\txt}

\count2=1 %even registers for local assignments
\LetCsVar{test\the\count2}{\txt}

% \txt can change here
\def\txt{Holla}
txt: {\tt\meaning\txt}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter
\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter
\b
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter{\GetCsVar{test\the\count2}}

{\tt\meaning\b}

or as a macro

\def\foo#1#2{%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter
\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter
#1%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter{\GetCsVar{#2}}
}

\foo\abc{test\the\count2}

{\tt\meaning\abc}
\bye
```

`\foo` above is the same as the later requested `GetCsVarExp` apart from the argument order so you could instead use:

```
\def\GetCsVarExp#1#2%
{%
\expandafter
\def
\csname#2\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
{\csname#1\endcsname}%
}


\GetCsVarExp{test\the\count2}{d}
  
{\tt\meaning\d}
```

Comment: Wow! That are many expandafters :-) Thank you for this, it works! But its so much code i have to type every time when i want to use \GetCsVar. I do not find a way to put this in a macro for a more easy call.

Comment: I put an easier way of this in my Edit above, but i am searching for an even more easy way :-)

Comment: Your definition of \foo doesn't work for me. I had to move the first { right before the first \expandafter, but than the result is not the right one, but something like `macro: \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \GetCsVar ->test\the \count 1`

Comment: @coonlight I added a `\GetCsVarExp` version without the `\let` to a temporary name

Comment: Great, David. The new `\GetCsVarExp` works fine! :-) Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 1):

The `tokcycle` package, while intended for other purposes, has the expansion infrastructure built into it.  It will allow a simpler definition of `\GetCsVarExp` plus allow specified levels of expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\GetCsVarExp[3][]{\cytoks{}%
  \addcytoks[#1]{\csname#2\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\def\csname#3\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\the\cytoks}}
\begin{document}
% Save content of a macro via \csname
\def\LesVar#1#2{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname=#2}% #1=name, #2=definition
% Get the previous saved content of a macro via \csname
\def\GesVar#1{\csname#1\endcsname}% #1=name

\def\txt{Hallo\thinspace you}
txt: \meaning\txt  % prints: txt: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you

\count1=1
\LesVar{test\the\count1}{\txt}

% \txt can change here
\def\txt{Holla}

\GetCsVarExp{test\the\count1}{A}% 0 EXPANSIONS
A: \meaning\A

\GetCsVarExp[1]{test\the\count1}{B}% 1 EXPANSION
B: \meaning\B

\GetCsVarExp[2]{test\the\count1}{C}% 2 EXPANSIONS
C: \meaning\C

\GetCsVarExp[x]{test\the\count1}{D}% FULLY EXPANDED
D: \meaning\D
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the result is required in PlainTex, that is no problem, as `tokcycle` is available there, as well:

```
\input tokcycle.tex
\long\def\GetCsVarExp[#1]#2#3{\cytoks{}%
  \addcytoks[#1]{\csname#2\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\def\csname#3\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\the\cytoks}}

% Save content of a macro via \csname
\def\LesVar#1#2{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname=#2}% #1=name, #2=definition
% Get the previous saved content of a macro via \csname
\def\GesVar#1{\csname#1\endcsname}% #1=name

\def\txt{Hallo\thinspace you}
txt: {\tt\meaning\txt}  % prints: txt: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you

\count1=1
\LesVar{test\the\count1}{\txt}

% \txt can change here
\def\txt{Holla}

\GetCsVarExp[0]{test\the\count1}{A}% 0 EXPANSIONS
A: {\tt\meaning\A}

\GetCsVarExp[1]{test\the\count1}{B}% 1 EXPANSION
B: {\tt\meaning\B}

\GetCsVarExp[2]{test\the\count1}{C}% 2 EXPANSIONS
C: {\tt\meaning\C}

\GetCsVarExp[x]{test\the\count1}{D}% FULLY EXPANDED
D: {\tt\meaning\D}

\bye
```

Comment: but the OP is using plain tex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what to do to get a new macro after `\GetCsVar` with the meaning `macro:->Hallo\thinspace you` like the `\txt`-macro.
>
> The problem is to expand `\GetCsVar` and `\the \count 1`  and `\csname`  but not the initial `\thinspace`.

If you really want to do it via expansion, be aware that three single expansion steps need to be triggered which requires inserting sequences of 2<sup>k</sup>-1; k=3 tokens `\expandafter` = 7 tokens `\expandafter`.

The first expansion step delivers the replacement text of `\GetCsVar` with parameters replaced by the arguments grabbed from the token stream. That replacement text is a `\csname..\endcsname`-thingie.

The second expansion step turns the `\csname..\endcsname`-thingie into the corresponding control sequence token. In case that control sequence token is not already having a meaning/is undefined in the current scope, then it (only in the current scope, even if `\globaldefs` has a positive value) also is given the meaning of the primitive `\relax`.

The third expansion step - in case it is expandable - delivers "toplevel-expansion" of that control sequence token.

---

But I suggest avoiding expanding the macro whose definition/meaning is to be "copied":

- In the edge case of the ⟨replacement text⟩ of the definition of the macro to be copied containing several consecutive hashes, the ⟨replacement text⟩ of the definition of the macro which holds the copy might be different from the ⟨replacement text⟩ of the definition of the macro which holds the original. This is because two consecutive hashes `##` in the ⟨replacement text⟩ of the definition of a macro are collapsed into a single hash `#` at the time of obtaining the replacement text due to expanding that macro.
- You loose information about definition-prefixes like `\long` (or `\protected` when using a TeX-engine with builtin expansion-protection.)

You might not have heard about the `\expandafter\endcsname\csname`-trick yet...

In order to avoid the need of expanding macros and hereby loosing information about definition-prefixes and hereby facing the circumstance that with each expansion amounts of consecutive hashes occurring in the replacement text are halved I suggest using only `\let`, no intermediate scratch-macro-assignment.

```tex
\tt

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\GetCsVarExp#1#2{%
  \expandafter\let\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1\endcsname
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Save content of a macro via \csname
\def\LetCsVar#1#2{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname=#2}% #1=name, #2=definition
% Get the previous saved content of a macro via \csname
\def\GetCsVar#1{\csname#1\endcsname}% #1=name

\def\txt{Hello\thinspace you}%
txt: \meaning\txt % prints: txt: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you

\count1=1
\LetCsVar{test\the\count1}{\txt}%

% \txt can change here
\def\txt{Holla}%

\GetCsVarExp{test\the\count1}{d}%

d: \meaning\d      % prints: d: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you.

\bye
```

Let's exhibit the difference by defining a macro which expands to a bunch of hashes and seeing what happens to the definitions when "copying":

```tex
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\tt

\def\GetCsVarExpcoonlight#1#2{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ax
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \csname#1\endcsname
  }%
  \expandafter\let\csname#2\endcsname=\ax
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\GetCsVarExpUlrich#1#2{%
  \expandafter\let\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1\endcsname
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Save content of a macro via \csname
\def\LetCsVar#1#2{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname=#2}% #1=name, #2=definition
% Get the previous saved content of a macro via \csname
\def\GetCsVar#1{\csname#1\endcsname}% #1=name

\def\SomeHashes{Initially there are 16 hashes: ################}%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\LetCsVar{SomeHashes0coonlight}{\SomeHashes}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes0coonlight\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes0coonlight\endcsname 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\GetCsVarExpcoonlight{SomeHashes0coonlight}{SomeHashes1coonlight}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes1coonlight\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes1coonlight\endcsname 

\GetCsVarExpcoonlight{SomeHashes1coonlight}{SomeHashes2coonlight}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes2coonlight\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes2coonlight\endcsname 

\GetCsVarExpcoonlight{SomeHashes2coonlight}{SomeHashes3coonlight}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes3coonlight\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes3coonlight\endcsname 

% This would yield an error as the single hash is taken 
% for s.th. that denotes a parameter in wrong ways (single
% hash not trailed by single digit in range 1..9; no
% parameters declared in the definition's parameter text, thus
% parameters #1 .. #9 may not occur in the replacement text) :

%\GetCsVarExpcoonlight{SomeHashes3coonlight}{SomeHashes4coonlight}%
%\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes4coonlight\endcsname:\hfil\break
%\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes4coonlight\endcsname 


%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\LetCsVar{SomeHashes0Ulrich}{\SomeHashes}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes0Ulrich\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes0Ulrich\endcsname 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\GetCsVarExpUlrich{SomeHashes0Ulrich}{SomeHashes1Ulrich}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes1Ulrich\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes1Ulrich\endcsname 

\GetCsVarExpUlrich{SomeHashes1Ulrich}{SomeHashes2Ulrich}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes2Ulrich\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes2Ulrich\endcsname 

\GetCsVarExpUlrich{SomeHashes2Ulrich}{SomeHashes3Ulrich}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes3Ulrich\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes3Ulrich\endcsname 

% This does not yield an error:

\GetCsVarExpUlrich{SomeHashes3Ulrich}{SomeHashes4Ulrich}%
\expandafter\string\csname SomeHashes4Ulrich\endcsname:\hfil\break
\expandafter\meaning\csname SomeHashes4Ulrich\endcsname 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\bye
```

[image]

---

In case you are interested:

As described in answers to other questions, using `#{`-notation you can implement a macro `\CsNameToCsToken` with the following syntax:

`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`

(`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` may be empty.)

Definition in plain-TeX:

```tex
\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00 %
\long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
\long\def\InnerCsNameToCsToken#1#2{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
```

(Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is obtained by triggering two expansion-steps, e.g., by having two "hits" with `\expandafter` which requires sequences of 2<sup>k</sup>-1; k=2 tokens `\expandafter`= sequences of 3 tokens `\expandafter`.)

With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:

`\CsNameToCsToken{foo}` → `\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{foo}` → `\newcommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{foo}` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{foo}` → `\NewDocumentCommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{foo}` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{foo}\bar` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\foo{bar}` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{foo}{bar}` → `\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\foo{bar}` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}=\bar` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let\foo={bar}` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\global\let{foo=}{bar}` → `\CsNameToCsToken\global\let\foo={bar}` → `\global\let\foo=\bar`  .

With `\long\def\PassFirstToSecond#1#2{#2{#1}}` and `\def\bar{AAA}`:
`\CsNameToCsToken\PassFirstToSecond{bar}{\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\def\expandafter{foo}\expandafter}`
→ `\PassFirstToSecond\bar{\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\def\expandafter{foo}\expandafter}`
→ `\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\def\expandafter{foo}\expandafter{\bar}`
→ `\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\bar}`
→ `\def\foo{AAA}`  .

---

In your scenario you could do:

```tex
\tt
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00 %
\long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
\long\def\InnerCsNameToCsToken#1#2{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def\txt{Hallo\thinspace you}
txt: \meaning\txt  % prints: txt: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you

\CsNameToCsToken\let{test1}=\txt
test1: \CsNameToCsToken\meaning{test1}% prints: test1: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you

\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let{test2}={test1}%
test2: \CsNameToCsToken\meaning{test2}% prints: test2: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you

\CsNameToCsToken\let\teeext={test2}%
teeext: \meaning\teeext % prints: teeext: macro:->Hallo\thinspace you

\bye
```

[image]

---

In a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712544/expansion-of-a-macro-defined-with-csname#comment1771064_712544) you say you couldn't find out how to set all the `\expandafter`.

You might be interested in the answers to [How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320933).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to go into such complications. If you want an infrastructure to do repeatedly things like these, it's quite easy.

```
\def\LetCsVar#1#2{% #1=name, #2=definition
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname=#2%
}
\def\LetCsVarCs#1#2{% #1=name, #2=definition
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#2\endcsname
}
\def\DefVarCs#1#2{% #1=name, #2=definition
  \expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname#2\endcsname
}

\tt\frenchspacing

\def\txt{Hallo\thinspace you}
txt: \meaning\txt

\count255=1
\LetCsVar{test\the\count255}{\txt}

% \txt can change here
\def\txt{Holla}

\LetCsVarCs{a}{test\the\count255}
a: \meaning\a

\DefVarCs\b{test\the\count255}
b: \meaning\b

\bye
```

Note that `\LetCsVarCs` does the same as your `\GetCsVarExp` (only with reversed order of arguments).

[image]

By the way, `\break` is completely out of place where you use it.