# \expandafter within a \begingroup ... \endgroup

Tags: tex-core, best-practices, expansion, grouping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does \begingroup\expandafter…\endgroup do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24393/what-does-begingroup-expandafter-endgroup-do)

In many of Heiko Oberdiek's packages one sees this type of construction:

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdf@filesize\endcsname\relax
  \ifxetex
    ...
```

What is the purpose of enclosing the `\expandafter` commands within a `begingroup...\endgroup`? What are the advantages of such an approach?

Comment: Oh sorry @egreg's answer (and the following discussion in comments) is more complete as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

oh sneaky Heiko:-)

It tests whether the csname was undefined (or relax) but in the case that it was previously undefined, it leaves it undefined as the implicit definition to `\relax` happens inside the group.

plain TeX:

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname aaaa\endcsname\relax
\show\aaaa
\fi

\expandafter\ifx\csname bbbb\endcsname\relax
\show\bbbb
\fi


\bye
```

produces:

```
(./heiko.tex
> \aaaa=undefined.
l.3 \show\aaaa

? 

> \bbbb=\relax.
l.7 \show\bbbb

? 
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it has to do with avoiding undue filling of the hash table.

The snag with

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdf@filesize\endcsname\relax
  ...
\else
  ...
\fi
```

is that it isn't expandable. With eTeX, you can use `\ifcsname` instead. If it is a control sequence, and not name, you are testing, you can use `\ifdefined` instead. But Heiko creates platform-independent packages.

You can think also of *etoolbox* packages's definition of `\csletcs`:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\csletcs}[2]{% [2011/01/03]
  \ifcsdef{#2}{\expandafter\let
    \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname#2\endcsname}{\csundef{#1}}%
}
```

The *catoptions* package defines this as (using a pseudoname here):

```
\def\letnames#1#2{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter
  \endcsname\csname#2\endcsname
}
```

since `\let` is not expandable anyway. This leaves `#1` and `#2` undefined if `#2` was originally undefined.