# Is a TeX macro defined?

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals

I am looking for a way in TeX to check if a macro was defined.

Currently I use a rather tangled way. I exploit a sort of side effect when comparing two macros via `\ifx`; this command returns:

- true,  if both macros are undefined,
- false, if one macro only is defined.

Therefore, given a surely undefined macro `\undefined` and the macro `\CheckMe`, which may or may not be defined, I can use:

```
\ifx \CheckMe \undefined
  CheckMe is NOT defined
\else
  CheckMe is defined!
\fi
```

Is this correct? Can we define a macro `ifdef`? working like:

```
\ifdef CheckMe         %or \ifdef \CheckMe 
  CheckMe is defined!
\else
  CheckMe is NOT defined
\fi
```

I tried with something similar:

```
\def\ifnotdef#1{\ifx \csname#1\endcsname \undefined}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is e-TeX allowed?

Comment: @egreg: Difficult to say. Actual problem is I have a large project. Sometime I prefer to compile single files. The idea is to define  a `\def\nostandalone\true` in the main package; in the child files, to be sometimes be compiled alone, I would set on the top:`        ` 

    \ifx \nostandalone \undefined
     \documentclass{paper}
     \begin{document}
    \fi
    ....
    \ifx \nostandalone \undefined
     \documentclass{paper}
     \begin{document}
    \fi

So it should be possible to load e-TeX before `\documentclass{paper}` with TeX methods.

Comment: If you are using LaTeX, then e-TeX extensions are enabled by default, unless you're using a very old TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg: thanks, I didn't explore e-Tex possibilities.

Comment: LaTeX defines a number of conditionals to check whether a macro is defined/not: `\@ifdefinable`, `\@ifundefined` Why not use them directly as part of your `\ifdef`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't define a macro `\ifdef` that can work with nested conditionals, because of the way TeX keeps track of `\else` and `\fi`. With a naive definition such as

```
\def\ifdef#1{\ifx#1\undefined}
```

one could surely say

```
\ifdef\CheckMe
  \string\CheckMe\space is not defined
\else
  \string\CheckMe\space is defined
\fi
```

but a construction such as

```
\ifnum\Acount=\Bcount
  something else
\else
  \ifdef\CheckMe
    \string\CheckMe\space is not defined
  \fi
\fi
```

will break if `\Acount` is equal to `\Bcount`, leaving a stray `\fi`: the `\else` will be matched to the first `\fi`, not to the second, because TeX doesn't expand tokens that are skipped in the true or false branch of a conditional; since `\ifdef` is a macro and not a conditional, the mismatch will bite you.

A workaround (tracing back to Knuth himself) is to define a macro in the following way:

```
\def\isundefined#1{TT\fi\ifx#1\undefined}
```

and call it as

```
\if\isundefined\CheckMe
  \string\CheckMe\space is not defined
\else
  \string\CheckMe\space is defined
\fi
```

This works also in nested conditionals because TeX will *see* the `\if` and match it with the correct `\else` or `\fi`. When expanded, `\if TT\fi` will do exactly nothing, leaving control to the following `\ifx`.

---

If e-TeX is allowed, there's an `\ifdefined` conditional that avoids choosing a macro name and trusting it will remain undefined:

```
\ifdefined\CheckMe
  \string\CheckMe\space is defined
\else
  \string\CheckMe\space is not defined
\fi
```

(notice the reversal of the conditions).

Comment: +1 `\ifdefined` is what I need!

Answer (score 9):

Changing slightly your definition, you will obtain Knuth's `\ifundefined`:

```
\def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax}
```

It has some limitations, but seems to be that you need.

Here http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2006p/index_html (Check if defined, no side effects by Bernd Raichle) you can find a deeper approach, with comments.

Comment: Also covered in [macros - What does \begingroup\expandafter…\endgroup do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24393/250119).