# What would be a suitable replacement for ifcsname in a non-etex situation?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

From the `pgfkeys.code.tex` file:

```
% This is useful:

\def\pgfkeys@ifcsname#1\endcsname#2\else#3\fi{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsnam
e\relax#3\else#2\fi}%
\ifx\eTeXrevision\undefined%
\else%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\pgfkeys@ifcsname\csname ifcsname\endcsname%
\fi
```

The command `\pgfkeys@ifcsname` is used internally to check if a key exists.  If `etex` is present, it is simply `\ifcsname`.  If not, then it is a fallback which (in the cases where it is used) is deemed good enough.

However, it doesn't work well with nested conditionals.  It is sometimes used via another command:

```
\long\def\pgfkeysifdefined#1#2#3{\pgfkeys@ifcsname pgfk@#1\endcsname#2\else#3\fi}
```

The problem here is that if `#2` or `#3` contains another conditional then because `\pgfkeys@ifcsname` uses macro parameter matching instead of conditional matching, then an `\else` or `\fi` inside `#2` or `#3` can get matched instead of the given ones.  Adding braces wouldn't work since that would add an extra set of braces.

Now, I intend reporting this on the PGF bug list, but thought I'd have a go at coming up with a replacement first.

I thought of:

```
\def\pgfkeys@ifcsname#1\endcsname{\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax\expandafter\iffalse\else\expandafter\iftrue\fi}
```

So my question: does this suffer from any more problems that the original didn't already suffer from?

(So the fact that `\csname undefinedcommand\endcsname` makes `\undefinedcommand` into `\relax` is not an objection to the new definition as it already exists in the original one.)

Comment: you are missing an `\expandafter` `\ifx\csname#1` compares `csname` and the first token of `#1`, with the expandafter it suffers from same syntax problem as original. Really they ought to use `\if\@undefined{#1}` so the `\if` token is exposed (egerg had an answer on this the other day, I'll look it up)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117188/is-a-tex-macro-defined/117190#117190

Answer (score 13):

The PGF code is wrong under many respects.

1. Delimiting arguments with `\else` and `\fi` doesn't help when the macro is used nested in other conditionals.
2. The macro gives different results if the argument is `relax`, depending whether e-TeX is available or not.

I'd use the usual indirect approach:

```
\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\@pgfkeys@csname#1\endcsname{%
  TT\fi
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  \iffalse\iftrue
  }
```

to be used as

```
\if\@pgfkeys@csname something\endcsname
   true case%
\else
   false case%
\fi
```

There is *no* way to define a “macro conditional” that behaves correctly in nested conditional. The other approach is to use argument conditionals in LaTeX style with the usual `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo`, basically the same as

```
\@ifundefined{macro}
  {<not defined or \relax case>}
  {<defined and not \relax case>}
```

It's easy to "reverse" this to get an `\@ifdefined` macro, just exchange `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` in the definition of `\@ifundefined`.

See [Is a TeX macro defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117188/is-a-tex-macro-defined/117190#117190)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It's explained in my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117188/is-a-tex-macro-defined/117190#117190

Answer (score 11):

It is important to note that regardless of the definition of `\pgfkeys@ifcsname`, it cannot be used within another TeX conditional safely: trying to do `\if[...]\pgfkeys@ifcsname...\endcsname...\fi...\fi` will lead to the first `\fi` closing the first `\fi` closing the `\if`, and the second `\fi` being unused.  However, the current definition of `\pgfkeys@ifcsname` does not even let other TeX conditionals be used within its branches, and this can be fixed.

---

A small comment first: you probably forgot to put `\expandafter` before the `\ifx` in your definition, to expand the `\csname`.  Let's put it back:

```
\def\pgfkeys@ifcsname#1\endcsname
  {%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\iffalse
    \else
      \expandafter\iftrue
    \fi
  }
```

The layout I chose is what is intended: if the `\csname#1\endcsname` construction yields `\relax`, then we want to call `\iffalse` and take the false branch which follows (because the command `#1` was not defined), otherwise call `\iftrue`.  This, unfortunately, fails.

- If the command does not exist, the `\ifx` test is true, TeX sees `\expandafter`, expands `\else`, which causes it to jump to the matching `\fi`, but... there is no matching `\fi`, since TeX sees `\iftrue\fi` as a nested conditional.
- If the command exists, the `\ifx` test is false and tries to skip to the following `\fi`.  But it sees an `\iffalse` conditional, an `\iftrue`, the `\fi` matching `\iftrue`, and there would have to be two more `\fi` to close the `\if...`s.

Several approaches exist to avoid mixing up conditionals:

```
\def\pgfkeys@ifcsname#1\endcsname
  {%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    \iffalse\iftrue
  }
```

with `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` defined as in LaTeX, `\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}` and `\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}`.  Or

```
\def\pgfkeys@ifcsname#1\endcsname
  {%
    \csname
      \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
        iffalse%
      \else
        iftrue%
      \fi
    \endcsname
  }
```

To be extra robust, one can even avoid using a parameter delimited by `\endcsname` at the price of using an auxiliary function:

```
\def\pgfkeys@ifcsname{\expandafter\pgfkeys@ifcsname@\csname}
\long\def\pgfkeys@ifcsname@#1%
  {%
    \csname
      \ifx#1\relax
        iffalse%
      \else
        iftrue%
      \fi
    \endcsname
  }
```

Here I decided to make `\pgfkeys@ifcsname@` long, in case the control sequence that is tested happens to be `\par`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle See my edit above the line.