# How to reliably obtain a control sequence token which is undefined?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

How to reliably obtain a control sequence token which is undefined in the current scope?

E.g., is there a sequence of tokens *⟨stuff⟩* with which you can do

`\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\dosomething\csname ⟨stuff⟩\endcsname`

so that

- TeX won't deliver any error-message while producing the control sequence token from the `\csname..\endcsname`-expression and
- the resulting control sequence token behind `\dosomething` in any case is undefined after processing `\endgroup`?

I could use this for reliably letting another control sequence token equal to something that is undefined.

By now I do s.th. like `\let\token=\UndeFineD` and hope for no piece of third-party-code defining `\UndeFineD` before the `\let`-assignment is performed.

Another approach could be a loop for constructing names of control sequence tokens until one is found where a test like

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand\CheckWhetherDefined[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  }{\endgroup\@firstoftwo}%
}%
```

or like

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand\CheckWhetherDefined[1]{%
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
```

does yield `\@secondoftwo`.

But I wonder if there is something more clever.

Perhaps an edge case of a `\csname..\endcsname`-expression - something of similar "edgeiness" to the scenario of using "frozen-`\relax`" in situations where you need a token which definitely is not an explicit character-token and which definitely never is defined in terms of `\outer`.

---

Please notice that the focus of the question is not on methods for testing whether a control sequence token is defined/undefined.

I ask for the best way of obtaining a control sequence token that is undefined in the current scope.

In this context, a test for "definedness/undefinedness" would only be a means to an end, e.g., if one chooses the path of creating tokens until one is created that is not defined.

---

"Academic question": is there an easily implementable method in TeX to enumerate all possible control sequence names?

Comment: While I find the question interesting, I don't see the practical relevance. Isn't the kernel relying on `\undefined` being undefined? If it isn't, it would break right along your code. More generally, LaTeX heavily relies on conventions anyways, like that `\relax` is the TeX primitive and not something else (or undefined). Relying on `\undeifned` isn't really different, is it?

Comment: It seems to me in latex `\@undefined` plays that role, though there's no warranty. (`\undefined` is the one used by plaintex, and some packages uses its own ones, for example `etoolbox` uses `\etb@undefined` in `\undef` and `tikz-pgf` uses `\pgfutil@undefined`).

Comment: see the definition of `\@ifundefined` in recent released which use `\ifcsname`

Comment: although if you are being passed a token rather than the character tokens representing the name, just do `\ifx\token\@undefind`

Comment: What you are asking for is fundamentally impossible because TeX can redefine its own syntax, so even if there was a primitive (or combination of primitives) that would result in an undefined control sequence, there is no way to prevent the surrounding code from redefining those primitives to break this behavior. As already said by the other comments TeX macro code heavily relies on convention, so best go for something like `\undefined` or `\@undefined`. Anybody defining any of those is clearly asking for trouble.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle or `\ifdefined`... :)

Comment: @HenriMenke TeX's capability of redefining its own syntax is the reason why I ask the question. Having TeX create an undefined token on the fly is nice in some situations. Safely doing so would be even nicer. I am well aware that safety in TeX (and computing in general) can be achieved at large only by obeying convention and that therefore there is not much safety in TeX (and in computing in general) .

Comment: If you assume that `\AwesomePackageByUlrichDiezAssumesThisIsUndefined` is undefined, there is basically no way aside from malice that anything will go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work even without e-TeX. It builds the control sequence names inside a group, checks against `\relax`, if they are equal closes the group, rechecks against `\relax` and only if that latter check is false uses the resulting control sequence.

Control sequence names are build using a numeric name (and if every numeric names would be taken precedes with a dot, putting more and more dots in front of the name until an undefined cs is found).

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\@=11
\long\def\@firstofone#1{#1}
\@firstofone{\endgroup
\long\def\@secondofthree#1#2#3{#2}
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\newcount\undefinedto@count
\newcount\undefinedto@maxcount
\undefinedto@maxcount=2147483647
\long\def\undefinedto#1%
  {%
    \undefinedto@{}%
    {#1}%
  }
\def\undefinedto@
  {%
    \begingroup
    \global\undefinedto@count=-\undefinedto@maxcount
    \undefinedto@loop
  }
\def\undefinedto@loop#1%
  {%
    \expandafter\undefinedto@loop@
      \csname #1\the\undefinedto@count\endcsname
      {#1}%
  }
\long\def\undefinedto@loop@#1#2%
  {%
    \ifx#1\relax
      \expandafter\@secondofthree
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
      {\undefinedto@test#1{#2}}%
      {\undefinedto@loop@next{#2}}%
  }
\def\undefinedto@loop@next#1%
  {%
    \ifnum\undefinedto@count=\undefinedto@maxcount
      \expandafter\@secondofthree
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
      {%
        \global\undefinedto@count=-\undefinedto@maxcount
        \undefinedto@loop{#1.}%
      }%
      {%
        \global\advance\undefinedto@count1
        \undefinedto@loop{#1}%
      }
  }
\long\def\undefinedto@test#1#2%
  {%
    \endgroup
    \ifx#1\relax
      \expandafter\@secondofthree
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
      {%
        \begingroup
        \undefinedto@loop@next{#2}%
      }%
      {\undefinedto@found#1}%
  }
\long\def\undefinedto@found#1#2{#2#1}
}

\undefinedto\show
```

Answer (score 6):

You could random-sample control sequence names until you find one that has not been defined

pdfTeX-only

```
\catcode`@=11

\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\long\def\@ifcsname#1{%
  \ifcsname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\long\def\@uniquecsname#1{%
  \@ifcsname{#1}%
    {\expandafter\@uniquecsname\expandafter{\number\pdfuniformdeviate\maxdimen}}%
    {#1}%
}

\def\uniquecsname{\expandafter\@uniquecsname\expandafter{\number\pdfuniformdeviate\maxdimen}}

\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\meaning\csname\uniquecsname\endcsname

\bye
```

Comment: According to the doc for `rand` fp function in `texdoc interface3`, sec. 28.9.3 _Operators_, `\pdfuniformdeviate` is provided in pdftex and (u)ptex and `\uniformdeviate` is provided in xetex and luatex. So with small effort this could work for several engines.

Answer (score 6):

The following is similar in spirit to Henri's answer, but builds the control sequence name predictably in a loop instead of using random numbers.

This should work in every engine with e-TeX.

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\@=11
\catcode`\^^@=12
\unexpanded{\endgroup
\protected\def\provideundefinedcsto#1%
  {%
    \begingroup
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \expandafter#1\csname\provideundefinedcsto@{^^@}\endcsname
  }
\def\provideundefinedcsto@#1%
  {%
    \ifcsname #1\endcsname\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    \@gobble{\provideundefinedcsto@{#1^^@}}^^@%
  }
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\long\def\@gobble#1{}
}

\provideundefinedcsto\show
\bye
```

Comment: How many `^^@`-characters can a control-sequence-name have?

Comment: @UlrichDiez That is limited by TeX's memory, for me the limit was at 3156 in pdfTeX. In LuaTeX the limit is 4996 (input stack size of 5000) with my defining loop.

Comment: Side note, see also [macros - What does \begingroup\expandafter…\endgroup do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24393/what-does-begingroup-expandafter-endgroup-do?rq=1) for a longer explanation on `\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can avoid e-TeX, in particular `\ifcsname`. If your aim is to *really* undefine some token, you can do a loop with integers, which will avoid long strings.

```
\def\undefine#1{%
  \begingroup
  \count255=0
  \buildundefined
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname\the\count255\endcsname
}
\def\buildundefined{%
  \immediate\write20{Testing \the\count255}% for debugging
  \ifcsname\the\count255\endcsname
    \advance\count255 by 1
    \expandafter\buildundefined
  \fi
}

% just for testing
\def\token{token}
\def\0{}
\def\1{}
\def\2{}

\immediate\write20{\noexpand\token is \meaning\token}

\undefine\token

\immediate\write20{\noexpand\token is \meaning\token}

\immediate\write20{\meaning\3}

\bye
```

The console output is

```
\token is macro:->token
Testing 0
Testing 1
Testing 2
Testing 3
\token is undefined
undefined
```

and the last line shows that the control sequence used for the `\let`, in this case `\3`, is still undefined at the end of the job.