# How can I place conditional statements in a LaTeX file dependant on how I'm processing it?

Tags: pdftex, conditionals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect which TeX engine is used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13172/detect-which-tex-engine-is-used)
>   [Conditional typesetting / build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build)

I'm currently writing a document in LaTeX (using the `article` `documentclass`  for now, thinking about switching to `memoir` later on).

I'm using the `navigator` package to generate additional meta-fields in the resulting `pdf` and I use `pdflatex` to generate my PDF.

However, when I use `latex` to generate a `.dvi` I do get errors because the meta-fields for `pdf` don't make sense now.

How can I put some conditional statements in the file so that certain sections would be included or excluded depending on what command is used to generate (or what target format is being generated)?

Here are the statements that now I have to manually comment out to compile my document with `latex`.

```
\usepackage{navigator}
\setparameter navigator:
author = Andy
title = Agile
\par
```

If this is a FAQ/stupid question please point me in the right direction.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need what appears to be a duplicate workflow (Ie pdf *and* dvi)?

Comment: Because if I leave those uncommented and run 'latex' I get errors. And I want duplicate workflow, because I want to process this document also into plain text with dvi2txt or something like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package [`ifpdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifpdf) detects whether the current mode is PDF or DVI:

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf
  \usepackage{navigator}
  \setparameter navigator:
  author = Andy
  title = Agile
  \par
\fi
```