# How to write a LaTeX command that could discriminate if it's being called with pdfLaTeX in order to use PSTricks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, pdftex, pstricks, luatex

I'm writing a class for LaTeX, and I need to make it general. I want to include a simple image, a logo, within the class, which would be inserted into the document as a simple command `\insertCompanyLogo`. To avoid extra files, I added the PostScript definition of the logo in the `.sty` file.

```
% Include PSTricks package
\usepackage{pstricks}
% Create new command to insert logo
\newcommand{\insertCompanyLogo}{
  \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
  \begin{pspicture}(180,180)
     \psline(0,0)(180,180) %The actual image is far more complex
  \end{pspicture}
}
```

This works good when I compile the document with `latex <filename>`. However, it fails when I try to use `pdflatex`.

In order to use PSTricks with `pdflatex`, some modifications are required. For example, I can add in the `.sty` file `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`.

Then compile the document using `pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>`. But this won't be general, and it won't work using the regular `latex` command.

My question is: Is there any way to define a command that understand if the document is being compiled with `pdflatex` or `latex`? That way I can add a couple of `\ifthenelse{}{}{}` to the include line of PSTricks. Thus, the document that uses this `.sty` class and calls the `\insertCompanyLogo` could be compiled with both commands without any modification.

I hope I was clear enough. And any solution, tip, recommendation or workaround, as always, is more than welcome.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I think that packages like `xelatex` and `asymptote` that could make this easier. But I would like this to work with a standard TexLive or MiKTeX installation, which is probably what 95% of the users of this class will have installed

EDIT 2: This question was marked as duplicate. The other questions address the engine issue (pdflatex vs. latex). Helpful information. But they leave out the PSTricks part, and how to make its use flexible and multi-engine, and that was the reason of my question.

EDIT 3: At the end, I opted for a completely different solution. What I wanted was to put a logo with a macro that works with both engines, `latex` and `pdflatex`. I used `TiKz`

```
\documentclass{article}
% Include package TiKz
\includepackage{tikz}
% Create new command to insert logo
\newcommand{\insertCompanyLogo}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3.25) 
    -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\insertCompanyLogo
\end{document}
```

The actual logo, and the contents of the `tikzpicture` environment, I got them from Inkscape, with an extension to export to `TiKz` format.

Comment: I think that [ifpdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifpdf) should help.

Comment: Things are confused here.  @MMA is right about `\usepackage{ifpdf}` for distinguishing between (say) using `latex` vs `pdflatex`.  There is also `\usepackage{ifplatform}` for conditionals based on the OS; and `\usepackage{ifxetex}` and `\usepackage{ifluatex}` for when you want to do special things depending on which **engine** you wish to use (the XeTeX engine and the related `xelatex` command are not packages).  Between `ifplatform`, `ifpdf`, `ifluatex`, and `ifxetex`, you're pretty much covered, I think....

Comment: Thanks guys. That definitely will help.

@Werner: Sorry for posting the question in the wrong forum. Won't happen again

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Detect which TeX engine is used](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13172/5764) and [Conditional typesetting / build](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33576/5764)

Comment: That is _not_ a dublicate because it belongs to using PSTricks which is not answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a bit tricky because `\ifpdf` cannot be used with `xelatex` which allows PSTricks code. The following example works with `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\providecommand\insertCompanyLogo{}
\newif\ifPSTricks \PSTrickstrue
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifpdf
  \PSTricksfalse
  \ifxetex\PSTrickstrue\fi
\fi

\ifPSTricks
  % Include PSTricks package
  \usepackage{pstricks}
  % Create new command to insert logo
  \renewcommand\insertCompanyLogo{%
    \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(180,180)
       \psline(0,0)(180,180) %The actual image is far more complex
    \end{pspicture}}
\fi

\begin{document}

PSTricks code is \ifPSTricks\else not \fi possible: \insertCompanyLogo 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Herbert for the answer. It solves the issue stated in my question. I was actually trying to make PStricks works with different engines, not run it conditionally. But I didn't say it on my question.

I did a bit more of research and found `TikZ`. I converted my logo into this format, using an Inkscape extension, put it into my class, and now `\insertCompanyLogo` works like a charm in pdflatex and latex.

Now, should I edit my question with this TikZ info? Or should I leave it like that?