# Detect whether running on pdfTeX or Knuth's TeX for conditional include

Tags: macros, pdftex, plain-tex

Does anyone know a way to detect whether one is running in `pdfTeX` or Knuth's `TeX`?  I want to be able to conditionally include extra features when a document is being built using `pdfTex`, but also support original `TeX` as a fallback.

Something like

```
\ifdefined\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpagewidth 8.5 true in
\pdfpageheight 11 true in
\fi
```

would get the job done -- however the above relies on the `e-TeX` extensions and doesn't build on Knuth `TeX`.

Thanks

Comment: Then use `\ifx\pdfpagewidth\undefined \else ... \fi`. This doesn't rely on `e-TeX` extensions. It will work also with `tex` executable.

Comment: @vacan1ty: Please unaccept my answer and choose another one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

Since `\csname foo\endcsname` expands to `\relax` if `\foo` is not defined, it's possible use `\ifx....` to compare the command sequence to be equal to `\relax`. This does not need `e-TeX` at all.

```
\newif\ifknuthtex
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfpagewidth\endcsname\relax
\knuthtextrue
\else
\pdfpagewidth 8.5 true in
\pdfpageheight 11 true in
\fi

This is \ifknuthtex Knuth's \TeX\else pdfTeX\fi
\bye
```

Compiling with `tex` gives the image below.

[image]

Comment: @vancan1ty: You're welcome. Happy `TeXing`

Comment: This doesn't work. There is a missing `\expandafter`. Try with `tex`  and you will get an error. I guess the image was generated before the update. Besides `\ifx\pdfpagewidth\undefined` works equally well.

Comment: @jfbu: I updated after a suggestion by Joseph Wright, but did not test. I reverted to the old version. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the problem with the reverted-to old version is that it leaves then control sequence `\pdfpagewidth` defined with meaning `\relax` if you run by Knuth's tex. This could fool later tests or force them to act like LaTeX `@ifundefined` (which does like your old code). The idea with the `\begingroup...\endgroup` and suitable `\expandafter`'s is to avoid this after-effect. But `\ifx\pdfpagewidth\undefined` has no _such_ after-effect and works. However it would be falsified if code like your reverted-to old version (now current) was executed earlier (or LaTeX `\@ifundefined`).

Comment: @jfbu: I'll investigate this. Apparently I am missing some point here I don't see at the moment. I asked the O.P. to unaccept and choose a better answer instead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I was so impressed by your gesture (wonder who upvoted?) that I forgave you on the spot for not telling which one of the better answers to accept `;-)`

Comment: @jfbu: Hm, the best answer is .... (fill in yourself ;-)) Alas, the O.P. did not react to my 'request' so far

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [iftex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/iftex?lang=en) "package". According to the documentation

> This very simple package, for both Plain TeX and LaTeX,
>   defines the `\ifPDFTeX`, `\ifXeTeX`, and `\ifLuaTeX` boolean
>   for testing whether PDFTeX, or XeTeX, or LuaTeX is being
>   used for typesetting.

Comment: Oh my, I could have bet that there's a package ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer there are also [`ifluatex` and `ifxetex`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13175/10038) packages, although, I am not sure why you would use them over `iftex`.

Answer (score 6):

If you only plan to distinguish between Knuth TeX and `pdftex` (or LuaTeX), this does it:

```
\begingroup\escapechar=-1
\edef\undefined{\string\undefined}%
\edef\test{\meaning\pdftexversion}%
\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\let\expandafter\ifknuthtex
\csname if\ifx\undefined\test true\else false\fi\endcsname

\ifknuthtex
  \message{Knuth TeX}
\else
  \message{Not Knuth TeX}
\fi
```

One assumption is made: that no previous macro file or loaded format defines `\pdftexversion`. If you want that `\ifknuthtex` returns the correct truth value also with XeTeX, you can load `ifxetex`:

```
\input ifxetex.sty
\begingroup\escapechar=-1
\edef\undefined{\string\undefined}%
\edef\test{\meaning\pdftexversion}%
\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\let\expandafter\ifknuthtex
\csname if%
  \ifnum 0=%
    \ifx\undefined\test 0\else 1\fi
    \ifxetex 1\fi
    true\else false\fi
\endcsname

\ifknuthtex
  \message{Knuth TeX}
\else
  \message{Not Knuth TeX}
\fi
```

Comment: excuse me, what does mean  `Knuth TeX` I think it's `pdftex` and `etex` now?

Comment: In TeX Live (and also in MiKTeX, I guess), calling `tex` launches the original program with no extension and we use to call it “Knuth TeX” for better clarity.

Comment: you're right for miktex I was ignore that

Comment: `\ifx\numexpr\undefined`.

Comment: @jfbu Not really: you can make a format for `pdftex` that doesn't load e-TeX extensions, but it's not the same as Knuth TeX nonetheless. Try `pdftex -ini '\show\numexpr'`

Answer (score 6):

For your problem, I strongly suspect that:

```
\ifx\pdfpagewidth\undefined
\else
  \pdfpagewidth 8.5 true in
  \pdfpageheight 11 true in
\fi
```

is, for all intents and purposes, quite fine enough. No need for complications.

Solutions based on a `\csname..\endcsname` approach have the drawback that they actually *create* a control sequence with meaning `\relax`, if the control sequence did not exist beforehand. Hence people do tricks with a bunch of `\expandafter`'s to have this meaning exist only briefly and then disappear after the `\ifx` test. However the TeX memory will have a new entry, even for such a briefly existing control sequence, as also does the simple fact of writing `\pdfpagewidth` in your source code (if not commented out).

Unfortunately as soon as some code does the `\csname..\endcsname` approach without the alluded-to precautions, the simple `\ifx\pdfpagewidth\undefined` test above will become dysfunctional. And this is the main reason, I guess, that people are reluctant to recommend it. One should be aware that LaTeX's `\@ifundefined` creates precisely this problem. But on modern installations, `latex` executable is using `pdftex` binary  (with in particular `e-TeX` extensions enabled), hence this is not Knuth TeX. On more ancient installations naturally you can have Knuth TeX + LaTeX format.

Note also that sometimes one may think (depending possibly on how your IDE presents things) that one is executing the Knuth TeX `tex`, whereas in fact it is `pdftex`  in dvi output mode.

The `\ifx\pdfpagewidth\undefined` could also be compromised by some earlier code which has given a meaning to `\undefined`, but that would be very condemnable thing.